# Политика относительно вопросов с инспекцией кода (code review)

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, тематика, инспекция-кода

Как сообщество относится к вопросам с предложением провести инспекцию (ревью) уже имеющегося кода?

На сайте имеется несколько подобных вопросов, и отношение к ним неоднозначное. Предлагаю определиться.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Так как у нас нет аналога [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), и вряд ли он нам светит (у нас даже Super User и Server Fault считаются слитыми со Stack Overflow), то предлагаю **разрешить** подобные вопросы.

Рекомендации для запросов ревью должны быть те же, что и на Code Review SE. В частности, там [онтопиком считается](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) запрос предложений по работающему коду:

- Лучшие практики и использование паттернов
- Проблемы с уязвимостями
- Производительность
- Корректная работа в непредвиденных случаях

[Критериями хороших вопросов](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) являются:

- Наличие реального работающего кода (никаких гипотетических примеров)
- Содержательный заголовок (никаких "как улучшить код")
- Отсутствие избыточных слов в заголовке (никаких "не могли бы вы проверить")
- Указание назначения кода (что код делает и зачем)
- Описание, откуда этот код взялся (интервью, соревнование и др.)

Правда, учитывая, что сайт не специализирован на ревью, шансы, что пользователи предоставят вопросы в идеальном виде, практически нулевые. В связи с этим придётся вручную доводить их до нормального состояния.

Comment: Полностью **за**, только чрезмерные придирки к словам типа "как улучшить код" (конечно, я  предполагаю, что кроме этой фразы в вопросе есть что-то содержательное, помимо самого кода) не нужны. В общем -- "зрим в корень".

Comment: Не боитесь вопросов "как мне улучшить по скорости `printf("kekeke")` ? PS: я больше за, чем против. Но нужно строго регламентировать и вынести на отдельную страницу в хэлпе.

Comment: @Nofate да, отдельная страница нужна, чтобы можно было сразу отсылать к ней при необходимости.

Comment: поддерживаю. Я бы добавил, что такие вопросы должны иметь обязательную метку (аналог `[code-review]`), чтобы было ясно какие ответы приветствуются. Полезное сообщение в тему: [What distinguishes Code Review from Stack Overflow?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5778/6143).

Comment: @jfs Есть [tag:инспекция-кода].

Comment: В следствии большого положительного отклика среди участников сообщества, спешу предложить рассмотреть вопрос более конкретно. Для этого, было бы здорово, если бы вы, как автор инициативы, привели два изменения для справочного центра в базовом виде. 1) Изменения для страницы «[На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)». 2) Рыбу отдельной страницы, детально раскрывающей принципы вопросов такого рода. В будущем, возможно, понадобиться еще добавить дополнительную причину закрытия связанную с инспекцией кода.

Comment: Этот вопрос проходит?
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692902/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java

Answer (score 11):

Сделал описание для метки [инспекция-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0). Предлагаю дополнять и улучшать

> Запросы на инспекцию (ревью) кода. Предлагайте только работающий код. Обязательно опишите реализуемый функционал и назначение кода. Используйте стандартный для языка стиль кодирования — имена функций и переменных, отступы, пробелы и прочее. Подробная инструкция есть в полном описании.

---

> Запросы на инспекцию (ревью) кода.
>
> Подходящие темы для таких запросов:
>
> - Лучшие практики и использование паттернов
> - Проблемы с уязвимостями
> - Производительность
> - Корректная работа в непредвиденных случаях
>
> Критериями хороших вопросов являются:
>
> - Наличие реального работающего кода
> - Содержательный заголовок
> - Отсутствие избыточных слов в заголовке
> - Указание назначения кода
> - Описание, откуда этот код взялся
>
> Подробнее: [Политика относительно вопросов с инспекцией кода (code review)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1761/)

Comment: Нчитался этого описания создал вопрос и на те на прикрылы сам вопрос Этот вопрос проходит?
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692902/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java

Comment: @FORTRAN у вас содержимое вопроса не в самом вопросе, а по ссылке на гитхабе. А должно быть в вопросе. И закрыто именно с такой формулировкой: «должны включать ... минимальный код ... прямо в вопросе»

Answer (score -1):

Проблема всех этих вопросов и просьб "посмотреть код", "улучшить код" в том, что:

1. Они практически все opinion-based или too broad.
2. Авторы вопросов особо не парятся по поводу локализации проблемы.
3. Как правило, это портянки кода, из которых:

   1. Мало что понятно.
   2. Сложно ревьюить код, не представляй картины общей по проекту в целом.

Разрешить можно очень конкретные запросы. К примеру, по оптимизации алгоритма: ускорить, уменьшить потребление памяти и т.п. А вот вопросы вида "как мне улучшить архитектуру", "я начал изучать ООП, помогите улучшить иерархию классов" следуют закрывать.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150115/discussion-on-answer-by-suvitruf-andrei-apanasik---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer) или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.