# Вопросы с инспекцией технической документации

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, тематика

Мы практически единодушно решили, что вопросы по инспекции кода нам нужны и интересны. ([Политика относительно вопросов с инспекцией кода (code review)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1761/181472)). А что насчёт вопросов по инспекции технической документации?

Недавно был задан вопрос по инспекции кода на C: «[Ревью библиотеки двусвязных списков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/488525/181472)».

Кроме самого кода там есть ссылка на репозиторий на гитхабе, где кроме файла с кодом есть `readme.md` с описанием использования кода. Я прочитал этот документ. С учётом того, что я знаю о программировании и о технической документации, мне есть что сказать автору. В документе есть пара мест, которые усложняют использование кода кем-то кроме автора:

- Неоднозначное описание функции;
- Непонятный синтаксис `$имён` переменных, нехарактерный для C;
- Требования к узлу списка мне кажутся неполными;
- Нет лицензии.

Тут возникает некоторое затруднение. Я мог бы предложить автору выставить и `readme` на инспекцию, но вопросы такого рода мы ещё ни разу не встречали и не обсуждали. Поэтому пока что я предложил обратную связь в виде [пулл-реквеста](https://github.com/maksspace/mylist/pull/1), чтобы создать пример.

В данный момент в сети Stack Exchange об этом можно спросить, наверное, на:

- Writers. Но там далеко не все программисты и анализ технической стороны не проведут. Для документации на русском неприменимо.
- ELL или Russian Language, если вопрос по переводу на английский.

Запрос на инспекцию технической документации на русском языке задать вовсе негде.

Предлагаю обсудить возможность включения таких вопросов и требования к хорошему вопросу.