# Ссылка на сайт Stack Exchange, чьей тематике, возможно, будет соответствовать вопрос, закрытый «не по теме»

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия, тревоги

### Актуальное поведение

Задаёт участница или участник вопрос, не соответствующий тематике сайта → вопрос закрывается с подобным шаблоном:

[image: Сообщение о закрытии]

В нём нет ничего, что помогло бы участнице или участнику продолжать поиски ответа на вопрос.

---

---

### Желаемое поведение

#### Для закрывающего

Закрывающая/ий видит сообщение, не соответствующее тематике → `Рекомендуется закрыть` → `не по теме, потому что...` → `В сети Stack Exchange есть другой сайт, более подходящий для этого вопроса` → выбор соответствующего сайта из списка ниже, куда предлагается задать тот же вопрос → Отметить вопрос тревогой.

#### Для оставляющего тревогу

`Тревога` → `должен быть закрыт...` → `не по теме, потому что...` → `В сети Stack Exchange есть другой сайт, более подходящий для этого вопроса` → выбор сайта из списка → `Отметить вопрос тревогой.`

Данный порядок действий не сильно увеличит время, затраченное на закрытие или тревогу.

#### Для автора закрытого вопроса

Автор вопроса после закрытия видит и шаблон примерно следующего содержания.

> К сожалению, Ваш вопрос, скорее всего, не соответствует тематике Stack Overflow на русском. Но, вероятно, он соответствует тематике `$имя сайта из списка и гиперссылка` (на английском), `$краткое_описание, какие вопросы разрешены на сайте, куда направляют автора`.

Пример,

> К сожалению, Ваш вопрос, скорее всего, не соответствует тематике Stack Overflow на русском. Но, вероятно, он соответствует тематике [**Super User**](https://superuser.com/) (сайт на английском), служащего для помощи по вопросам об аппаратном и программном обеспечении.

---

---

### Аргументы

1. Основная задача Stack Overflow — взаимопомощь между участниками, а не соревнование, у кого больше сарказма в концовке предложения «Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что ...». Существующий шаблон никак не помогает найти автору найти ответ на свой вопрос.
2. Вероятность, что участница или участник в дальнейших поисках ответов перейдёт на сайт, не относящийся к сети Stack Exchange, чьим сотрудникам невыгодно терять аудиторию.
3. Неприятно, когда ожидаешь помощи, а вместо этого решают, соответствует ли вопрос тематике или нет. После бюрократической отписки у автора может создастся негативное впечатление о сайте.
4. Подозреваю, не только новички, но и некоторые опытные (не = мета-активные) участники не знают о существовании некоторых сайтов из списка, где немалая вероятность получить качественный ответ на вопрос.

---

---

### Список сайтов

#### Не включал бы

1. Вообще никак или слабо связанные с программированием или системным администрированием, например, [**Martial Arts**](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/).
2. Сайты Stack Exchange, чья тематика дозволена на Stack Overflow на русском, как то [**Server Fault**](https://serverfault.com/) или [**Code Review**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1762/199934).
3. Сайты Stack Exchange, вопросы по которым дозволены на других сайтах из списка. Например, вопросы по Emacs можно задавать не только на [**соответствующем сайте**](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/), но и в Super User. Вероятно, такие сайты и не следует исключать, но тогда список может сильно расшириться.

#### Включил бы

- [**Super User**](https://superuser.com/) — чья тематика — вопросы по hardware и software;
- [**Software Recommendations**](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) — вопросы вида «посоветуйте программу, соответствующую `$определённым требованиям`»;
- [**Hardware Recommendations**](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) — то же, но для аппаратного обеспечения;
- [**Information Security**](https://security.stackexchange.com/) — если вопрос по информационной безопасности, но не относится непосредственно к программированию;
- [**Webmasters**](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) — тут спрашивать о SEO;
- [**Web Applications**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) — посылать, если задают про Facebook, Twitter, YouTube и т. п.;
- [**Personal Productivity**](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/) — там IT-вопросов немало, хоть присутствуют не только они;
- [**User Experience**](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) — для вопросов вида `$посоветуйте, как поступить в данной ситуации в сфере IT, исходя из личного опыта`. Не воспрещаются «вопросы, на которые нельзя дать однозначный ответ». В основном, спрашивают по дизайну сайтов, но в онтопик попадают и другие вопросы, связанные с взаимодействием человека и компьютера.
- [**Software Engineering**](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) — сюда я попадаю из Google в поисках общетеоретических, не связанных с конкретными проблемами, вопросами программирования, например, [**Why does it matter that HTML and CSS are not programming languages?**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/28098);
- [**Graphic Design**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) — если спрашивают по GIMP, Photoshop и т. п.;
- [**Mathematics**](https://math.stackexchange.com/) — раз в Stack Overflow на русском часто спрашивают математику.

Если считаете, что в списке необходимо что-либо ещё, добавляйте.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Причины закрытия - предложение добавить en.so в варианты более подходящих сайтов](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4039/208074)

Comment: Я бы поспорил про половину перечисленных...

Comment: [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/) != [Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) :) Взял на себя смелость исправить этот пункт.

Comment: @D-side, спасибо!

Answer (score -2):

## Аргументы против

1. Разработчики сайта должны потратить время, на то чтобы реализовать новую фичу (вместо того чтобы делать что-то более полезное)
2. Кто-то (видимо, менеджер сообщества) должен *регулярно* тратить своё время чтобы поддерживать список доступных сайтов в актуальном состоянии (вместо того чтобы делать что-то более полезное).
3. Вместо одной причины закрытия появятся две: с рекомендацией сайта и без. Меню тревог нагрузится дополнительным элементом. Там и так много причин, в которых часто путаются.
4. Закрывающие должны теперь будут разбираться в тематике **каждого из сайтов**, на которые даются ссылки. Много у нас тут участников, активных хотя бы на трёх сайтах сети?
5. Нет никакой уверенности и невозможно проверить, что автор вопроса знает английский и сможет сформулировать вопрос на рекомендованом ему сайте (только если текущий вопрос не задан на английском, но это нечастый случай).
6. В некоторых случаях "не по теме" означает "не по теме на любом сайте сети, потому что субъективно, слишком обобщённо, недостаточно информации или вообще непонятно что вы пишете". Пример: [Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587910/181472)

Comment: **1.** Для англоязычного SO функция [**реализована**](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4043/199934). Можно спросить у @Nicolas Chabanovsky, сложна ли была реализация. // **2.** Почему регулярно и почему вообще должен поддерживать? Предложено 11 сайтов — разве часто меняются названия или тематики сайтов? Если такое случается, то случаи единичные. Против же громоздкого списка я и сам высказался. // **3.** Новых пунктов в меню не не нужно, новые сайты добавляются [**сюда**](http://i.imgur.com/QNvOAty.png)...

Comment: но можно расширить список модераторов :-)

Comment: **4**. а) Сайтов не так уж много, см. п. 3, б) Неплохо было бы, если при закрытии самим закрывающим была бы показано сообщение, какие вопросы, считаются онтопиком на том или ином сайте сети. Как на скрине в п.3 показано, какая тематика на Мете, в) Разбираться полностью во всех нюансах необязательно, но прочитать сообщения (см п 4.б) и представить, что примерно соответствует. г) Поэтому в пример я добавил подстраховочные `вероятно` и `скорее всего`...

Comment: **5.** а) По этой причине добавил в пример дополнение `(на английском)`, б) Не раз встречал мнение, что без знания английского в IT делать нечего. // **6.** Пункты меню, которые выбирали закрывающие, если причины закрытия такие, какие описаны у Вас, останутся. Закрывающие могут выбирать любую из прежних причин. // Спасибо.

Comment: **1**-это и есть полезная фича. **2**-неужели нельзя автоматизировать поддержание ссылок на топ10? **3**-достаточно расширить существующий список сайтов. **4**-count me in. **5**-согласен. **6**-согласен

Comment: @СашаЧерных нет, для англоязычного SO реализована совсем другая функция. Там прямой перенос вопроса на другой сайт, а вы хотите чтобы появлялась рекомендация и ссылка, но без переноса. По этой же причине сайты-рекомендации не могут добавляться в список сайтов-целей для переноса, который вы показываете.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо, понял.