# Метка "Инспекция кода"

Tags: обсуждение, метки, инспекция-кода

> **"Инспекция кода"** - Запросы на инспекцию (ревью) кода. Предлагайте только работающий код. Обязательно опишите реализуемый функционал и
>   назначение кода. Используйте стандартный для языка стиль кодирования —
>   имена функций и переменных, отступы, пробелы и прочее. Подробная
>   инструкция есть в полном описании.

Например вопрос этот (не лучший, но все же):

[Подскажите, где ошибка в проверке совпадения логина с БД?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607690/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%91%D0%94)

Человек привел код, спрашивает, что не так.Почему не подходит под данную метку?!

Уже не первый вопрос и мой в том числе [утка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/14963/%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%A3%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%A3%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0) редактирует и убирает данную метку.

Вообще уже не понятно что и как можно задавать тут. "Почему не работает код ..." закрывают из-за просьбы отладки. "Что не так с кодом ... " опять не то.

Comment: Через чур строго и понятно что можно, что нельзя как-то размыто!

Comment: Ну у автора ошибка, раз он просит её найти. Это под code-review уже не попадает.

Comment: @Elena, Утка щас хотел напистаь подробный пост на мете что не так с меткой, Вы опередили)

Comment: @Elena, инспекция кода - это именно code review. Код-ревью это не "как мне запилить фичу", или "почему не рабтает". Это "я сделал так, укажите недостатки"

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка, "я сделал так, укажите недостатки" чем отличается от "я написал код, но он почему-то не работает". Лично я не понимаю

Comment: @Elena, вот поэтому мне название метки и не нравится, щааа подождите

Comment: @Elena неужели вы не видите разницы - "код работает" и "код **не** работает"?

Comment: Elena, смотрите: 1). Какой смысл по-вашему несет инспекция-кода если ее лепить просто если есть проблема? Здесь почти любой вопрос с проблемой =) Что есть метка что-нет.

Comment: @Elena, во-вторых метка задумывалась именно как cr: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1761/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-code-review

Comment: @Elena - cr, это когда ваш вроде бы рабочий код перед добавлением в общую кодовую базу проверяют на стилистику, использование всяких паттернов и нюансов технологии, соответствование требованиям команды и ошибки которые Вы могли бы увидеть. Такая практика в серьезных командах - почти обязательна.

Comment: @Elena, btw если вам не нравятся мои правки (или скажем мой клюв), необязательно писать об этом на мете: можно спросить меня лично зайдя в общую комнату чата  ruso: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow-- и упомянуть мой ник через собачку

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, "код работает" и "код не работает" ... если бы код работал, то ник то бы не задавал вопрос! Инспекция кода как раз подходит под такие вопросы, "я сделал код, но он почему-то не работает"

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка, мне не понятны Ваши правки потому я тут и задаю вопрос. Именно Вы во всех моих вопросах и правках именно эту метку удаляете.

Comment: @Elena ага (но не только в ваших вопросах), потому что мне не оч пофиг на эту метку, и я изредка в нее заглядываю: ревьювить куда интереснее чем разбираться в jquery-плагинах. Удаляю я ее не из вредности - а потому что вопрос к метке не относится (ну вы ж не ставите метку "тестирование" на вопросы? вот и инспекцию-кода - не надо, если это не cr).

Comment: на SO все время чувствуешь себя как на минном поле. Как задать вопрос, чтобы кто-то не отметил дубликатом или не закрыл, потому что якобы вопрос под "отладку кода" попадает, не ту метку поставил или еще что-то. Ответ пишешь - надо чуть ли не блогером быть, объяснить каждую букву и действие и неважно что автор вопроса уже ответил решением и поблагодарил за ответ. 
Ну хорошо хоть значки и шапки есть, хоть какой-то интерес еще есть

Comment: @Elena, ну вы не воспринимайте удаление метки или правку вашего вопроса как личное оскорбление, это нормально. Если хочется явный офтоп спросить, можно в том же чате.

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка, да при чем тут оскорбление и личное? Я же объяснила что не понятны действия. Не считаю оскорблением!

Comment: _Ответ пишешь - надо чуть ли не блогером быть, объяснить каждую букву и действие и неважно что автор вопроса уже ответил решением и поблагодарил за ответ._ - пояснения нужны не только для автора, но и для тех пользователей, которые могут прийти потом. Не обязательно объяснять каждую букву, достаточно описать решение, а не просто дать кусок кода, который неизвестно как работает.

Comment: @Elena, ну просто воспринимайте вопрос не как "художественно произведение" а как "описание технической проблемы", которое полезно не только вам, но и тем кто это нагуглит потом. Вот Вы ее описали, кто-то мимо проходил, увидел что "вот эта штука к проблеме не относится", снес метку, что логично.  Про минное поле - ну вот во время переезда с хк на русо оч любили приветствия из вопросов выпиливать. Вот тогда пожалуй было минное поле)

Comment: _Инспекция кода как раз подходит под такие вопросы, "я сделал код, но он почему-то не работает"_ - не подходит. Так как про это ясно написано в описании метки.

Comment: @Elena `Как задать вопрос, чтобы кто-то не отметил дубликатом или не закрыл` - Дело в том, что это База Знаний. База. То есть накопленный некий опыт передается остальным. Соответственно какой смысл не закрывать вопрос как дубликат, если было уже миллион одинаковых вопросов, а ответ на него уже есть. Зачем миллион раз писать один и тот же ответ? Никакого смысла стопицот раз отвечать, что формула площади круга S=π r2... если достаточно одного ответа на него... Проблема задающих, что они считают их проблему уникальной и не пользуются поиском.

Comment: @Elena и вы не поверите. но для ответа не надо писать километр текста. Иногда хватает и двух-трех строк

Comment: Думаю, вы не знакомы с термином code review. Он подразумевает рабочий код, который автор предлагает на обозрение, с целью получить советы по его улучшению. Пожалуй "инспекция кода" не лучший перевод, который сбивает с толку.

Comment: На англоязычном SO вообще отдельный сайт для code-review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка а у меня вопрос на счет ваших слов "интересно рьвьюить". Это правда так?) Потому что мне бы хотелось, чтобы кто-нибудь более опытный покопался в моем коде и сказал, что (всё) не так. Но мне сложно представить такого альтруиста, который будет читать дцать файлов кода)

Comment: @Matty, ревьювить в общем интересно - это однозначно так. Ревьювить дцать файлов кода - не особо, слишком много времени на вхождение. Обычно на ревью выставляют либо отдельную фичу, либо описание архитектуры с набросками классов/модулей, но без имплементации

Comment: @Matty, ну и собственно си - не мой конек, но если Вы будете выставлять какой-то нормально подготовленный модуль (ну то есть не тупо полотно, а описание чего делали, и на что хотелось бы обратить внимание), то на этом сайте найдется достаточно профессионалов чтобы его посмотреть.

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка хм... Doxygen как вариант подойдет? Там по сути разбор полетов с функциями, классами, методами и т.д. Если создать просьбу с ссылкой на эту документацию + парой кусочков кода для оценки стиля и прочего + описанием того, что вообще программка делает, это будет адекватно?

Comment: @Matty, понятия не имею что он выдает в результате, не использовал. Я ж говорю, я не сишник) Думаю будет адекватно если будет вопрос на отдельный не оч большой модуль с ясной целью а не на все и сразу. Если у вас на такие модули не побито, обычно что-то пошло не так)

Comment: @Matty, в общем попробуйте, вас не съедят, ну максимум вопрос закроют, потом переоткроют и закроют еще раз

Answer (score 16):

У данной метки есть краткое описание:

> Запросы на инспекцию (ревью) кода. *Предлагайте только работающий код. Обязательно опишите реализуемый функционал и назначение кода*. Используйте стандартный для языка стиль кодирования — имена функций и переменных, отступы, пробелы и прочее. **Подробная инструкция есть в полном описании**.

В котором четко указано, что предоставляемый код должен быть *рабочим*.

На случай, если данной краткое описание непонятно, есть [полное описание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/info), в котором даны критерии хороших вопросов, и подходящих тем для таких вопросов.

Критериями хороших вопросов являются:

- Наличие реального работающего кода
- Содержательный заголовок
- Отсутствие избыточных слов в заголовке
- Указание назначения кода
- Описание, откуда этот код взялся

Пройдемся по данному списку, на примере вопроса [Подскажите, где ошибка в проверке совпадения логина с БД?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607690/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%91%D0%94)

- наличие реального работающего код: в самом заголовке идет речь об ошибке
- содержательный заголовок: *где ошибка* - вряд ли можно назвать содержательным.
- Отсутствие избыточных слов в заголовке: с натяжкой можно сказать. что избыточные слова отсутствуют
- Указание назначения кода: отсутствует
- Описание, откуда этот код взялся: отсутствует

В итоге: вместо запроса предложений по рабочему коду получается портянка неизвестного кода, который неизвестно что делает, и при этом в нем **где-то** ошибка.

Как минимум этот вопрос не подходит под описание метки.

Как максимум данный вопрос нужно закрыть, с причиной

> Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.

---

Хотя судя по всему там проблема была вообще в опечатке.

Comment: "Наличие реального работающего кода" Зачем тогда задавать вопрос?!

Comment: @Grundy, я в чем проблема вообще не смотрел. Увидел метку cr - открыл вопрос, увидел что это не cr, снес метку, закрыл вопрос)

Comment: "Как максиму данный вопрос нужно закрыть, с причиной ...." no comment

Comment: @Elena, чтобы получить объяснение что можно сделать лучше.

Comment: @Elena, если проблематика вам непонятно, просто примите как данность, что есть люди которые хотят чтобы посмотрели на их работающий код. И для них нужна эта метка, для остальных - нет.

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка, "чтобы получить объяснение что можно сделать лучше." вот это стоит написать в описании метки и больше ничего! А то Вы уже раза 2 предлагали правку метки.

Comment: @Elena вот смотрите пример метки...кмк, оправданно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607379 .... у человека всё работает, но шматок кода большооооой получается, тяжелый.... а из ответов ясно, что можно это заменить на три строки кода...... то есть вот для чего метка: код рабочий, но хотелось бы узнать, можно ли улучший код, сократить, сделать его согласно неким общим практикам и т.д. Ибо возможно он (код)  неправильный, хоть и рабочий

Comment: @Elena, так предложите свою) Просто людям которые хотят получить cr, не нужно обычно объяснять что это такое и зачем оно) Общий принцип да - как сделать лучше. Насколько мой код понятен, следует практикам языка, насколько естественны используемые сущности etc.

Comment: @Elena: не ясно как можно не так понять фразу: *"Предлагайте только работающий код."* (на всякий случай: "работающий" подразумевает, что автор кода не знает ни об одном баге в коде). Вот [примеры](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/590491/23044) [вопросов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587653/23044) (чтобы пользу code review продемонстрировать). [В полном описании метки есть ссылка на вопрос явно объясняющий разницу между обычным Stack Overflow вопросам и Code Review](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/info)

Answer (score -4):

Я как раз взялся за эту метку и начал писать здесь пространный пост, но Елена опередила меня.

Проблема явно видна в вопросе Елены и ее комментариях: многие начинающие разработчики не знают и не понимают что такое код-ревью в принципе и зачем оно нужно. Поэтому лепят метку [инспекция-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0), [задуманную изначально для code-review вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2104/14963) куда попало, убивая семантику метки.

Я предлагаю метку [инспекция-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0) - сжечь. Заменив везде на синонимы [код-ревью](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d1%8c%d1%8e) или [ревью-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0) (Если этого нельзя сделать автоматически, я даже готов заняться этим во имя шапок =)).
Начинающие разработчики - врядли будут лепить незнакомые слова на вопрос.
Ну да, это явно англицизм, но термин вроде устоявшийся.

Comment: Синоним уже есть. Человек добавляет метку [код-ревью], она автозаменяется на [инспекцию кода].

Comment: @NickVolynkin проблема в том, что инспекцию-кода добавляют много, лишне и не по делу. Можно ли разом все заменить на синоним - я не знаю)

Comment: А через некоторое время народ сообразит, что надо лепить "ревью-кода", чтобы их код переписали и тогда нам опять придется придумывать новое непонятное слово? ИМХО все же надо работать с тем что есть и поднимать грамотность использования метки.

Comment: @Kromster, на самом деле нет, review не подразумевает под собой _переписывание_

Comment: @Grundy нам с вами это понятно, а для новичка это выглядит как "некто запостил простынку говнокода, получил полпростынки хорошего"

Comment: @Kromster, ну да, увы так. Но все-таки "код-ревью" больше похоже на термин чем "инспекция-кода", и возможно некоторые догадаются что просто так его лепить не стоит

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Название метки – субъективно. Кому–то кажется, что одно лучше, кому–то – другое. Синонимы позволяют исправить ситуацию. В любом случае, текущий вариант содержит русскоязычное название, "ревью–кода" – не является русскоязычной меткой.