# Вопросы по социальной инженерии по теме или нет?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, тематика

Социальная инженерия, как подраздел информационной безопасности, с уклоном в психологию и лингвистику, имеет ли право жить на ruSO?

Не будут ли вопросы по ней закрыты с пометкой "Не по теме"?

**Дополнение**

Добавил опрос в ответах, с целью узнать отношение сообщества ruSO к данным вопросам.

**Пояснение к опросу**

Подсчёт будет вестись по количеству проголосовавших ЗА тот или иной вариант: Да или Нет.

Для тех, кому недоступен просмотр голосов к ответу, статистика на данный момент такая:

- Да (+16/-8)
- Нет (+7/-12)

### Примеры ожидаемых вопросов

#### Пример 1

> Существуют сервисы, которые позволяют подменить исходящий номер
>   телефона, и в  связи с этим вопрос.
>
> Предположим вам позвонил ваш администратор (коллега) с номера
>   администратора (коллеги), с просьбой уточнить кое-какие данные
>   относительно ваших учётных данных, как удостовериться что:
>
> - это тот человек, за которого он себя выдаёт? (предположим голос
>     вы не помните, ибо редко общаетесь);
> - что он имеет право получить такую информацию?
>
> Есть ли какие-либо стандарты безопасности по передачи подобной
>   информации по телефону в организациях?

#### Пример 2

> Можно ли установить факт подмены номера в СМС? Если да, то каким
>   образом?

#### Пример 3

> На что следует обратить внимание при проверки достоверности
>   полученного email-сообщения?

Comment: Скорее всего будут.

Comment: Ну можно попробовать... Если очень постараться, то может и взлететь.

Comment: @Qwertiy наверное стоит сначала обсудить перечень примерных вопросов по данной тематике, которые будут норм и которые не норм...

Comment: Ну обсуждай, если хочется)

Comment: Без примеров сложно сказать. На сайте подобные вопросы были/есть?

Comment: @Kromster https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-engineering

Comment: учитывая что на русском языке такие нишевые сайты врядли появятся (в рамках SE), то если есть примеры хороших вопросов (см. как предлагают сайты на area51.SE) и нет *явных* возражений, то только улучшится сайт.¶ В тему из новостей http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2018/01/19/british-15-year-old-gained-access-intelligence-operations-afghanistan/

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на подобные инициативы, например, инициативу с [инспекцей кода](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1761/6).  Было бы очень здорово увидеть в предложении (в вопросе) какие–то более четкое описание, о каких именно вопросах идет речь, а также критерии их оценки. Если вы добавите несколько примеров ожидаемых вопросов, будет совсем великолепно!

Comment: Любопытные у голосования результаты образуются %)

Comment: @D-side ага, ноздря в ноздрю, а вообще на будущее достаточно одного ответа для голосования, так понимаю: +1 — За, -1 — Против.

Comment: @edem, 2 ответа лучше - можно ещё их обосновывать и писать комменты)

Comment: @Qwertiy не наш случай) В плане "обосновать"

Comment: Хм, а на каком основании вы устанавливаете свои правила подсчета голосов? Причем уже после начала опроса?

Comment: @PavelMayorov на основании здравого смысла.

Comment: @edem ваш здравый смысл почему-то отличается от моего

Comment: На ruSO нет метки "социальная инженерия".

Comment: @maestro всё верно, опрос как раз о том, позволено ли ей тут быть.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а как вы смогли закрыть как дубль, если там пока ответы не заплюсованны для этого?

Comment: @pavel Посмотрел справку и не нашел причин, почему я бы не мог его закрыть. Подскажите, пожалуйста, про какое именно правило вы говорите?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky вот если я попробую закрыть похожим способом. http://joxi.ru/ZrJpWjQh9jODL2 Я уточнил, это особенность модератора такая?

Comment: @pavel Возможно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky если таким образом добавлять по одной теме к тематике сайта, то получится куча. Если как сейчас вопросы програмирования и администрирования, то это кратко, ясно и понятно. А как это будет выглядеть с социальной инженерией "программирование, админитрирование и социальная инженерия". Я думаю если расширять, то на всю область IT, а не выбирать отдельные из неё кусочки. С другой стороны конечно в правилах можно её отдельно не выделять, но тогда никто и не узнает что писать можно, только случайно увидев вопрос по ней.

Answer (score 9):

Да, я хотел бы видеть вопросы по социальной инженерии на ruSO.

Comment: Но, только они должны быть отмечены, как вопросы относящиеся к данной категории.

Comment: @VladSpirin у всех вопросов свои метки, конечно.

Answer (score -6):

Нет, вопросы по социальной инженерии выходят за рамки данного сайта.