# Расширение тематики сайта: предложение добавить социальную инженерию

Tags: обсуждение, статус-отклонено, тематика

Данный вопрос–инициатива создан на основе предыдущего предложения «[Вопросы по социальной инженерии по теме или нет?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6769/)» [с учетом требований к вопросам–инициативам](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6835/).

**Обновление**

Пожалуйста, учтите следующее: Что значит отдать голос?

- *За или против вопроса*. Голосом «за» в вопросе вы говорите, что вы разделяете мнение, что проблема существует и ее необходимо решать прямо сейчас. Если вы не видите проблему или необходимости ее решения именно сейчас, пожалуйста, голосуйте «против».
- *За или против ответа*. Голос «за» или «против» ответа сигнализирует ваше отношение именно к самому предложенному решению.

Сейчас много голосов против на ответе, который говорит, что инициатива не нужна, но на сомом вопросе этих голосов нет, а должны он быть именно на вопросе!

---

## Инициатива

#### Спешу предложить сообществу рассмотреть *вопрос о расширении тематики сайта* — добавлении в нее социальной инженерии.

Социальная инженерия, как подраздел **информационной безопасности**, с уклоном в психологию и лингвистику. Социальная инженерия — метод управления действиями человека без использования технических средств ([Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

### Примеры ожидаемых вопросов

#### Пример 1

> Существуют сервисы, которые позволяют подменить исходящий номер
>   телефона, и в  связи с этим вопрос.
>
> Предположим вам позвонил ваш администратор (коллега) с номера
>   администратора (коллеги), с просьбой уточнить кое-какие данные
>   относительно ваших учётных данных, как удостовериться что:
>
> - это тот человек, за которого он себя выдаёт? (предположим голос
>     вы не помните, ибо редко общаетесь);
> - что он имеет право получить такую информацию?
>
> Есть ли какие-либо стандарты безопасности по передачи подобной
>   информации по телефону в организациях?

#### Пример 2

> Можно ли установить факт подмены номера в СМС? Если да, то каким
>   образом?

#### Пример 3

> На что следует обратить внимание при проверке достоверности
>   полученного email-сообщения?

Comment: Эм.. Чем этот вопрос отличается от предыдущего? Бред какой-то перезадавать те же вопросы, если вполне можно использовать тот.

Comment: @Qwertiy Отличия два, на мой взгляд: (1) в формулировке (здесь она явно говорит, что мы планируем сделать — изменить тематику), (2) во времени голосования и мети важное.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а зачем **два** ответа (не один)? Предполагается, что могут возникнуть и другие?

Comment: @D-side Вообще, да, в данном случае лучше иметь один ответ, так как второй есть голосование в самом вопросе. Зато мы видим, что даже с пояснениями почему–то коллеги голосуют довольно неоднозначно, так как у самого вопроса судя по всему рейтинг должен быть сейчас где–то +2, а не +10.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky предлагаю считать по голосовавшим **За** тот или иной вариант **ответа**, невзирая на сам вопрос, так не запутаемся. Например сейчас: 14 — За, 8 — Против и всё.

Comment: А решение как принимается, большинством голосов, или сколько нужно что бы "за" сработало, или каждый случай индивидуально рассматривается?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин [Я предполагаю](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6835/), что было бы разумно принимать инициативу, если за саму инициативу высказывается в два раза больше людей, чем против нее (то есть две трети голосов «за»).

Comment: @edem Да, согласен. Видимо, в данном случае так и стоит поступать. Все же, сам факт показывает всю неоднозначность голосования.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky просто в таком виде, от избирателя требуется два действия вместо одного, причём второе он может не сделать. Т.е. ему нужно проголосовать за какой-либо вариант, а затем проголосовать против другого, что не все кстати делают, когда голосуют За, а вот те, кто голосует Против в этом более активны.

Comment: Голосую **ЗА**, потому что тема относится к ИБ, но тем не менее, вопрос больше психологический, нежели технический, но все же требующий внимания.

Comment: Я не вполне понимаю необходимость этого предложения. У нас вроде бы не было в последнее время шквала закрытых как оффтопик вопросов по социальной инженерии. Почему тогда была выбрана именно эта тема? Почему мы думаем, что именно это волнует сообщество?

Comment: @VladD Это личная инициатива участника.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky да вот судя по его ответу, похоже, что часть намерений потерялась... :) И стоило скорее предложить ему самому привести вопрос в надлежащий формат.

Comment: Как минимум - **очень** размытая тематика, под нее пройдет почти все, что угодно... Категорически против. Тогда разрешение в сторону технических наук (той же математики) - как говорится, сам Бог велел... и что будет в итоге?

Comment: а как с этим обстоит у соседей на en.so, есть|разрешены ли там подобные темы ? я не говорю, о том, что нужно идти таким же путем, но вероятно такой же вопрос уже поднимался у них и хорошо бы было увидеть аргументы за и против

Comment: @Alex вопросов не наблюдал, явного разрешения социнженерии там нет, и на его Мете мне сходу ничего похожего найти не удалось.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky зачем удалили ответы с вариантами? И при отклонении инициативы пояснении какое-то бы не помешало.

Comment: @edem После [детального рассмотрения процесса совместного принятия решений сообществом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6899/6) стало ясно, что подобные ответы не несут никакой пользы, так как не добавляют знаний о проблеме («Для нас крайне важно понимать, почему это решение популярно, а не то, что оно популярно»). Скорее, они мотивируют просто нажать кнопку и уйти. Мы же хотим увидеть доводы за и против.

Comment: @edem Если коротко, то  «социальная инженерия» не будет добавлена в список допустимых на Stack Overflow на русском, так как она гуманитарная, а не техническая. Stack Overflow — это сообщество разработчиков и системных администраторов, нас объединяет любовь к техническим системам и решениям.  Если более развернуто, то надо сделать компиляцию из всех ответов. Я не знаю, на сколько это необходимо в данном случае.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky "подобные ответы не несут никакой пользы, так как не добавляют знаний о проблеме" вообще не вариант, предлагаете писать оды голосующим "За"? Эти ответы дают понимание о востребованности/невостребованности этой инициативы, а их удалили.

Можно просто обновить вопрос и написать, что по результатом голосования 48/25 или сколько там инициатива не прошла, а не потому что она "гуманитарная".

Comment: @edem Хорошо. Давайте восстановим ответы. Но не прошла она не по результатам голосования, а потому что не программирование очень далеко от социальной инженерии. В процессе рассмотрения подходов к инициативам, стало ясно, что распределение голосов не может быть однозначным критерием к принятию правила.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky вот, спасибо! Согласен.

Answer (score 25):

#### За

Голосуйте за этот ответ, если вы *хотите* видеть вопросы *о социальной инженерии* на Stack Overflow на русском.

Answer (score 11):

#### Против

Голосуйте за этот ответ, если вы *не хотите* видеть вопросы *о социальной инженерии* на Stack Overflow на русском.

---

Коллеги, кто голосует за этот ответ (против инициативы). Пожалуйста, отдайте ваш голос в самом вопросе!

Comment: Я против, но ответ за который поставил ранее не обдумав до конца уже не убрать. Считаю что либо брать всю область IT, либо как есть сейчас, так как брать из неё отдельные кусочки это создание кучи малы. В хелпе тема сайта написана: "Программирование и администрирование", это кратко и красиво звучит. А если будет "Программирование, администрирование и социальная инженерия", то это уже нагромождение, а если потом будет ещё 5-10 других близких к программированию областей, то будет логически очень сложно понять что относится к тематике сайта а что нет.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Вы можете проголосовать против самой инициативы (против вопроса).

Comment: Как убрать голос я разобрался, помогло редактирование.

Comment: это уже мозг взорвать можно, отдельно голосовать за-против сам вопрос, отдельно есть два вариант ответа, и кроме того за да и нет можно ответь + и -, мне это вообще непонятно.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин: к чему ответы опубликованы, в которых никаких доводов, полезных фактов не приведено не ясно. Если вы против, то как минус на самом вопросе поставьте так и плюс этому ответу поставьте. Чтобы понять, что можно добавлять, какие вопросы допустимы, что работает, что не работает, можно посмотреть на соответствующие английские сайты. В данном случае метка [`[social-engineering]` на security.SE](https://goo.gl/42fVZ2). Опыт с меткой [инспекция-кода] (аналог codereview.SE) показывает, что это ~может работать даже если требования к вопросам заметно отличаются

Comment: нафига 2 вопроса? Одного " да/нет (если да то голосовать, нет -
 голосовать против" достаточно.

Answer (score 10):

> Это сообщение не представляет никакого решения по инициативе, голосование за/против него никак не повлияет на результат её рассмотрения. Я надеюсь им проинформировать проходящих мимо участников и помочь им сделать более осознанный выбор.
>
> В отношении него действуют обычные правила Меты: плюсы в знак согласия, минусы в знак возражения. Конструктивные комментарии также приветствуются.
>
> Также, несмотря на то, что сообщение формально считается общим (особенность общности вопроса?), в первую очередь оно выражает моё личное мнение.

---

**Если коротко:** я считаю, что включать социальную инженерию в тематику сайта явно  *не нужно* (для приведённых примеров во всяком случае) и *бесполезно* (эффект будет минимальным) или даже *вредно* (здорово повысит количество ненужного шума). Что нам хватит того подмножества вопросов, связанных с социальной инженерией, что *уже лежит в рамках текущей тематики*. Что явное разрешение не нужно, но и о явном запрете речи не идёт.

#### Анализ примеров

**Пример 1** *будет закрыт* независимо от того, будет ли "социальная инженерия" в тематике сайта или же нет.

- Он "слишком общий": содержит много вопросов и зависит от характера данных и юрисдикции
- Он "не по теме" (да!), т. к. касается юридических норм о взаимодействии между людьми, безотносительно информационных систем (канал связи здесь лишь обстоятельство; можно не помнить, как человек даже **выглядит** и осознавать, что даже при личном общении его не узнаешь; представьте сотрудника, работающего удалённо, например).
- Если оставить в нём только вопрос о общедоступных стандартах и лучших практиках безопасности по части разглашения учётных данных, может и взлетит, можно обосновать тем, что многие из средств аутентификации — технические и должны быть предусмотрены разработчиком информационной системы.

**Пример 2** *уже* по теме (хоть и с некоторой натяжкой). SMS-сообщения сейчас не редкость в информационных системах, и вопрос о том, какие гарантии они предоставляют и кто их обеспечивает, очень актуален при разработке. Он не субъективен и достаточно ограничен, чтобы на него существовал небольшой, но хороший ответ.

Уверен, что если бы возник аналогичный вопрос об HTTPS (фактически с просьбой разъяснить, какие гарантии даёт PKI), его приняли бы хорошо. Если, конечно, он не был уже задан, просто я не смог его сходу отыскать.

**Пример 3** *уже* по теме, что особенно заметно, если переформулировать его: задать его не с позиции получателя, а с позиции *отправителя*: *"какие меры нужно предпринять создателю информационной системы (разработчику сайта?), чтобы сообщения от этой системы были проверяемыми на аутентичность/подлинность?"* — качественный ответ на этот вопрос покажет и то, как пользователи смогут обнаруживать подвох. Принятие многих из этих мер — задача как минимум из области системного администрирования, а иногда и программирования. А остальные, более "человеческие" меры сойдут как дополнение к техническим.

---

#### Анализ последствий и предостережения

Как и любые другие вопросы, в рамках тематики данного сайта, они должны соответствовать определённым критериям качества.

Рассмотрим на примерах действия пользователей что будет, если социальную инженерию **явно разрешить** в рамках ресурса? Вопросы о социальной инженерии **в отрыве от ИТ** будут закрываться по причинам *"нет объективно верного ответа"* и *"слишком общий"*.

- Кто-то будет при этом минусовать из соображений морали, хотя мы и [приняли явное решение не принимать их во внимание](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2868/181100). Кто-то будет даже выписывать закрывашки с мыслью "лишь бы не помогли"; хотя по правилам это злоупотребление механизмом закрывашек, для мнений есть голоса.
- Кто-то обратит внимание на то, что вопросу необходимо куда больше деталей об объекте атаки, чем разумно размещать в одном вопросе, ответ на который ожидается от случайных прохожих.
- Кто-то обратит внимание на то, что люди для людей крайне недетерминированные сущности и абсолютно любой прямой ответ на вопрос имеет шансы не сработать...

И если я прав, то результатом станет в первую очередь увеличение числа закрываемых вопросов. Не вижу в этом решительно никакой пользы. Зато вижу вред: лишний шум заминусованными вопросами (их и так больше, чем хотелось бы) и увеличение нагрузки на закрывашек.

Comment: Ну так по любой метке можно закрыть вопрос, как "Слишком общий", "Не по теме" и т.п. Никто не делает различия для "социальной-инженерии", как особенной метки.

Comment: @edem важно различать существование на сайте метки (что означает, что на сайте есть касательные вопросы, но сама метка необязательно тематична **целиком**, см. [tag:процесс], [tag:семантика], [tag:математика], из того что быстро нашлось на главной) и включенность в тематику сайта (что означает, что тематика приветствуется на сайте сама по себе и целиком).

Comment: Согласен, идея с внесением социальной инженерии в разрешённые темы официально это привлечение к этой теме внимания, а какой в этом смысл если по этой теме вопросов может быть 0.01%. Если ради таких в процентном соотношении тем делать отдельные правила, то правила превратятся в нагромождение хлама. Внутри группы модераторов этот вопрос можно лично решить, но к правилам это не должно относиться. Да и вообще по каждому такому микро-вопросу тратить своё время тем кто общается на мете не вижу смысла, время и силы на дело которое имеет минимальный профит.

Comment: Кроме того не всё вообще нужно покрывать правилами. Можно написать хоть 10000 правил пожарной безопасности, но кто в реальности всё это прочитает. Часто правила нужны, а часто правила это просто замусоривание пространства так как эти ситуации решаются логикой и здравым смыслом. Более того если правил много, например 100, то думаете много кто прочтёт больше 10? Адекватные правила должны быть немногословны и сразу выражать суть, желательно не иметь перечислений и исключений.

Comment: Что внимание будет привлечено это дело десятое. Да, то что тематика по сравнению с программированием и сисадминистрированием явно мелковата, мелкий, но фактор. А правил вряд ли когда-либо станет много -- как только объём станет некомфортным, будем обобщать или разделяться (хочется верить, компания Stack Overflow созреет для создания новых неанглоязычных сообществ).

Comment: @D-side я имею ввиду что сам вопрос надуманный, вы сами сколько вопросов по социальной инженерии видели на RU StackOverflow? Я не видел ни одного.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин то, что их не задают здесь, не значит, что их не возникает. Просто сюда с ними не идут, потому что здесь это не по теме. Разрешим -- придут. (И под натиском закрывашек скорее всего уйдут обратно :])

Comment: @D-side резонно. я поэтому и предлагаю сделать "программирование, администрирование и около", тогда интерес людей сможет быть удовлетворённым. Точнее не то что бы предлагаю как моя позиция, а как вопрос для рассмотрения, пока не ясно насколько это будет лучше или хуже. Лично я не против таких вопросов а скорее за, но и вопрос например какое питание наиболее полезно для программистов, или на какой клавиатуре меньше устают руки, мне тоже нравится. А где-же ещё такие вопросы задавать как не тут. Конечно это надуманые вопросы, но всё же.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин это слишком размытая формулировка для закрепления в правилах. Но да, это уже совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72649/discussion-between---and-d-side).

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ! Именно такие ответы ожидаются в вопросах–инициативах!

Comment: @edem поскольку ваш вопрос был создан до введения правил об инициативах, а сейчас признан дубликатом данной инициативы, а также метки [meta-tag:важное] не имел, нет, его нельзя считать началом общественных обсуждений. Убрал соответствующий кусок.

Answer (score 8):

> Это сообщение не представляет никакого решения по инициативе,
>   голосование за/против него никак не повлияет на результат её
>   рассмотрения. Я надеюсь им проинформировать проходящих мимо участников
>   и помочь им сделать более осознанный выбор.
>
> В отношении него действуют обычные правила Меты: плюсы в знак
>   согласия, минусы в знак возражения. Конструктивные комментарии также
>   приветствуются.
>
> Также, несмотря на то, что сообщение формально считается общим
>   (особенность общности вопроса?), в первую очередь оно выражает моё
>   личное мнение.

Я против данной инициативы и хочу высказать особое мнение.

- Расширение онтопика не должно быть простой процедурой, это должно занимать полгода и массу усилий. Иначе мы каждый месяц будем приписывать к тематике "...и администрирование", "... и ИБ", "...и пластиковые карты" и так далее.
- Расширение онтопика вполне разумно предварять бета-периодом, в течение которого заинтересованные в инициативе лица должны создать двадцать вопросов (которые не должны закрываться), на которых мы должны посмотреть различные типы вопросов, взвесить, насколько тематика вообще имеет спрос. Нет двадцати постов - инициатива никому не нужна, кроме автора.
- На текущий момент (это уже подчёркивалось) нет большого вала закрытых вопросов по социнженерии, зато я постоянно закрываю вопросы по теме "какие кнопки нажать в такой-то программе". Вот это я понимаю - спрос действительно существует. (Другой вопрос - хотим ли мы именно этот спрос на "продвинутого пользователя программ" или скажем на "математику")
- В результате того, что только одна инициатива может стоять на голосовании я уже не могу выставить любую другую инициативу (например, "давайте расширим тематику на всё ИТ"). Мы же понимаем, что нам не дадут уже создавать отдельные русскоязычные сообщества по ИТ на so, так почему с этой начали? Давайте вдумчиво обсудим, какие темы в целом нужны.
- Я не вижу по голосованию хоть сколько-то заинтересованных аргументов "за" инициативу, в основном приводятся мнения против. Кому-то просто пройти мимо и кликнуть "а пусть будет, от меня плюсик инициативе поставить не жалко" - а нам приходится в отрицании затрачивать большое количество часов для аргументации и отстаивания бесполезности идеи. Инициатива нужна кому-то кроме топикстартера и молча плюсовавшим?
- Мы расширяемся на тематику, которая многими расценивается как пустая бла-бла-бла говорильня, на которой можно нахаляву срубить репутации. Мы реально готовы уйти в широкий набор подобных тематик, вызвав волны негатива и разделения и так небольшого сообщества?

> Отдельно я собрал свои [замечания по
>   регламенту](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6876/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2)
>   и, хотя прекрасно понимаю желающих вообще избежать любых регламентов
>   (для мелких инициатив это действительно не нужно) - считаю, что для
>   расширения онтопика нужен достаточно веский барьер, преодолеть который
>   должны только стоящие инициативы.

Я совершенно согласен с постулатом, что неплохо бы расширить онтопик.

Но я предлагаю посвятить весь остаток до конца года обсуждению того, какие темы мы хотим видеть с начала 2019 года, а потом ввести их разом, чтобы на год-два иметь чёткие и понятные правила игры.

И поэтому я голосую в данный момент против инициативы, надеясь из хаотичного процесса выстроить более планомерный и понятный.

Как бы это могло выглядеть:

- Завести опрос/голосованием чтобы посмотреть, сколько людей вообще "за" и "против" расширения (причём с возвможностью учесть как невнятное "мне в принципе, некритично" до "я хлопну дверью и уйду с такого so)... У нас же достаточно большая масса людей, кто согласен с расширением онтопика, которые эпизодически где-то высказывались.
- Завести после ещё опрос/голосование длиной в квартал - предлагайте темы для расширения. Один ответ - одна тема, голосование на каждой. Допустим, кто-то пишет ответ "математика" или другой "физика" и так далее.
- И только после этого уже принимать общее решение о расширении тематик.

Comment: Согласен, пустая трата рессурсов и времени активной части сообщества вообще на незначимый вопрос. Ставить рамки и ограничивать решение годом я бы не стал, а просто позволил бы теме самой естественно провести свои процессы и естественным образом решиться, будь то месяц, год или три года. (+)

Comment: Наоборот, надо не тянуть кота за хвост, а просто сразу  расширить тематику  до всего, что связано  с компьютерами (и убрать всю дурь, разрешающую закрывать вопросы, как зависящие от мнений, невозможно дать однозначный ответ и т.п.)

Comment: @avp И это было бы гораздо более интересной инициативой, чем текущая. Не бесспорной, но гораздо более важной для сообщества.

Comment: Однако, вряд ли многие ее поддержат (они знают, что начальство будет против -))

Comment: @avp Я за то что бы не тянуть год, а принять решение в адекватные сроки, то есть как оно созреет. Для начала можно сделать тестовый период, если эксперимент окажется удачным - утвердить.

Comment: @avp согласен, предлагаю сделать более мягким отношение к "неподходящим вопросам" и закрывать, удалять и блокировать только в случае крайней необходимости. Выигрыша от таких закрытий крайне мало, но травмировать новых или даже старых участников смысла не вижу, закрытие вопроса стресс для автора. Надавать по рукам человеку очень просто, но и уйти с сайта на всегда тоже очень просто после такого, при этом даже опытному участнику.

Comment: Возможно, стоит взять для расширения оффтопика часть тех норм, что используются на Area 51 для рассмотрения новых сообществ. У меня уже возникло впечатление, что именно на них предлагаемый регламент и основан.

Comment: На мой взгляд, очень интересная мысль, что прежде чем поднимать вопрос о расширении тематики сайта, нам сначала необходимо иметь прецедент с каким–то количеством вопросов по данной теме. Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно нам стоит этот момент (какие критерии должны быть удовлетворены, чтобы поднимать вопрос о расширении тематики) рассмотреть отдельно? Простой список из нескольких правил, на мой взгляд, может значительно помочь как авторам инициатив, так и сообществу как–то количественно оценить необходимость и успешность затеи.

Comment: @avp, `и убрать всю дурь, разрешающую закрывать вопросы, как зависящие от мнений, невозможно дать однозначный ответ и т.п.` — вы иронизируете? Или всерьёз готовы видеть вопросы из разряда: «Что лучше, Windows или Linux» и «Когда искусственный интеллект сможет заменить человека»?

Comment: @Arhad, серьезно. Те, кому тема вопроса не нравится, могут даже не смотреть на него, у остальных же может получиться (конечно, может и не получиться) увлекательное обсуждение в ответах, комментариях и чатах

Comment: @avp, у нас не форум, а база знаний. А переливание из пустого в порожнее в ответах не несёт абсолютно никакого знания, только забивает сайт гипотезами.

Comment: @Arhad, в самом деле? Я все же остаюсь при своем мнении, что это должен быть  сайт вопросов и ответов, где вместо долгого поиска можно (в идеале) быстро получить ответ (причем в интерактиве) на вопрос, который сразу и сформулировать-то толком не получается. К сожалению, пока мы от такого идеала весьма далеко.

Comment: Обновил свой "дисклеймер", т. к. он, очевидно, понят не совсем правильно. Чтобы сохранить эффект, возможно, вы захотите обновить его и здесь :Р

Comment: @D-side Утащил себе обновленную шапку ответа.

Comment: _Но я предлагаю посвятить весь остаток до конца года обсуждению того, какие темы мы хотим видеть с начала 2019 года, а потом ввести их разом, чтобы на год-два иметь чёткие и понятные правила игры._ - нет, так не пойдёт - нельзя за раз вносить много изменений - всё развалится. А за остальную часть ответа плюс.

Answer (score 2):

#### Лирика

Сайт "Stack Overflow на русском", как и всё русскоязычное сообщество сети StackExchange, не располагает такими возможностями по расширению тематики обсуждаемых вопросов, какие имеются у англоязычного сообщества: Area51 и 100500+ ею порождённых сайтов сети StackExchange на английском языке, с возможностью создания новых.

Т.е. о создании новых русскоязычных сайтов в данной сети можно смело забыть.

И тем не менее, та основная тематика, которую предлагает ruSO, а именно: программирование и администрирование, становится для пользователей тесноватой. Это выражается в обсуждении юридических аспектов ПО (авторское право и прочее), математических вопросов, вопросов дизайна и уймы других пограничных тем, связанных с ИТ.

Некоторые из этих тематик обсуждались обществом на Мете заранее, как например вопросы по метке "инспекция-кода", а некоторые задавались по-тихому без задней мысли, как например вопросы по дизайну.

#### Основная часть

Задач же у данной инициативы несколько, а именно:

- оповестить о существующей тематике;
- узнать отношение сообщества к данному типу вопросов;
- определить критерии к вопросам, которые имеют место быть, в случае одобрения появления оных.

**По пунктам**

*Социальная инженерия* — это набор техник и методов, основанных прежде всего на знании психологии человека и психолингвистики, которые, вкупе с техническими средствами или без оных, позволяют влиять на человека с целью получения от него необходимых сведений или с целью влияния на его поведение в интересах "манипулятора".

Как можно догадаться из определения, это довольно таки обширная тема и многие вопросы по которой не могут быть рассмотрены на данном сайте, по ряду причин, например:

Вопросы, формально подходящие под категорию СИ, могут не относятся к ИТ или к ИБ в принципе, например: "Как эффективнее имитировать боли в животе, чтобы родители разрешили на этот раз не идти в школу?".

Сайт же "Stack Overflow на русском" это прежде всего сайт, имеющий основную тематику, от которой необходимо отталкиваться при расширении (дополнении) его тематикой по СИ.

**Т.е. вопросы по СИ должны быть непременно связаны с его основной тематикой: программированием и администрированием и ИБ, как подразделом администрирования. Это основной критерий, который будет давать право на жизнь данного рода вопросам на ruSO.**

Остальные же критерии являются вполне стандартными для данного сайта:

- вопрос должен быть по возможности конкретным, описывающим одну проблему (задачу);
- и на вопрос можно будет дать объективно обоснованный ответ.

И если придерживаться такого рода ограничений, то тематика сайта органично дополнится вопросами по СИ, которые тем не менее не будут являться "белой вороной" среди остальных вопросов ruSO, в случае если таких ограничений на них наложено не будет.

Comment: Так на минуточку, инициатива ж и предлагает добавить **в основную тематику** СИ, как самодостаточную для онтопичности вопроса на ruSO, наравне с программированим/администрированием. То множество вопросов, что вы обозначаете в конце вопроса, для ruSO уже уместно. В чём тогда смысл инициативы?

Comment: @D-side не знаю, изначально мой основной вопрос, дубликат который, рассматривал расширение тематики в рамках ИБ. Просто, предполагалось, что некоторые вопросы могут быть не совсем (совсем не) технического плана, а пограничные наподобие с юр.вопросами, которые могли бы быть закрыты.

Comment: Мде. Прекрасная ситуация получилась :)

Comment: @D-side да ладно, соц.инженерия априори рассматривается как часть ИБ, да и в самом опросе на этом был сделал акцент "Социальная инженерия, как подраздел информационной безопасности, с уклоном в психологию и лингвистику."

Comment: ИБ, кстати, вовсе не подмножество программирования и системного администрирования.

Comment: Перечитал несколько раз раздел "задачи инициативы". Я правильно понимаю, что вы готовы в случае одобрения инициативы на полгода испытательного периода для тематики, без расширения онтопика - чтобы были видны, что за вопросы вообще задаются и можно ли накопать по ней хотя бы двадцать вопросов?

Comment: @AK неправильно. Вы придумали, а мне соглашаться? Нормально)

Comment: *Т.е. вопросы по СИ должны быть непременно связаны с его основной тематикой: программированием и администрированием и ИБ, как подразделом администрирования.* - в **этих рамках** вопросы и так могут присутствовать на сайте, являясь топиком (администрирование). Зачем тогда создавать *расширение*, которое расширением, по-вашему, не является?

Comment: @Harry отчасти да, отчасти нет, потому что некоторые вопросы, как например вопрос первый из примеров, при текущем подходе могут быть закрыты, так как они скорее относятся к вопросам межличностного общения, в рамках ИБ, чем непосредственно к технической составляющей проблемы.

Answer (score 2):

Главное отличие темы «социальная инженерия» (она же её проблема) в том, что это совершенно не техническая тема. Она гораздо ближе к гуманитарным наукам вроде психологии.

> "Социальная инженерия — метод управления действиями человека **без использования технических средств**"

И какое это отсутствие технических средств имеет к техническому ruSO?

Так мы спокойно перейдем к вопросам, как втереться в доверие так, чтоб обокрасть квартиру, или там построить финансовую пирамиду - и все это на сайте "программистов и администраторов".

Утрирую? Да по сути нет, и если подумаете - сами поймете, какой это абсурд - социальная инженерия как раздел программирования...

Comment: В лучших традициях "жёлтой прессы": взять высказывание, вне контекста, выделить, **чтобы бросалось в глаза**, и на основе этого сделать нужный вывод. Если уж цитируете, то и ссылку на Вики добавьте, как в оригинале. Кстати @Harry вы её открывали?

Comment: Ваше право - считать, что можно засорять ruSO вот такой ерундой. Мое выделение - прием столь горячо любимой вами социальной инженерии, как и ваше голословное обвинение меня :)  При том, что мне как-то поясняли, что математические вопросы здесь офтопик, так как занимаемся сугубо программированием, если паче чаяния данное решение будет принято - я приложу все усилия к тому, чтобы математика стала еще одним расширением тематики ruSO как **куда более близкое** к программированию. Не сомневаюсь, кстати, что кто-то тут же начнет прилагать усилия для продвижения социологии и психологии...

Comment: @edem зачем? Она уже есть в вопросе, вместе с приведённой цитатой, что делает её априори релевантной.

Comment: Никто, впрочем, не утверждает, что это "раздел программирования", суть предложения лишь поместить её в список разрешённых тематик **рядом** с ним. Но именно по этой причине я против добавления этой тематики. Она **радикально** отличается от всего, что мы обычно рассматриваем "в рамках".

Comment: @Harry как и ваше право считать ерундой то, что ею не является ;) И да, никакого голословного "обвинения" не было, я лишь обратил внимание на то, что вы процитировали текст, без указания ссылки на Вики статью, в которой "технических средств" предостаточно, по этой теме, в то время как вы утверждаете будто тема СИ **вообще** без ТС обходится и доступна любому *гуманитарию*.

Comment: "если паче чаяния данное решение будет принято - я приложу все усилия к тому, чтобы математика стала еще одним расширением тематики ruSO как куда более близкое к программированию. " а если нет, то махнёте рукой?) Вообще, только за и по поводу математики.

Comment: @edem С тем же успехом можно воткнуть и социологию или историю - на том основании, что для обработки соответствующих данных или написания статей используются компьютеры...

Comment: @edem Да, если нет - махну рукой за отсутствием прецедента.

Comment: @Harry плохой пример про историю, из раздела, как шинковать огурцы на ноутбуке)