# Праймериз для инициатив

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Мы движемся в сторону увеличения бюрократизации в сообществе и меня сильно беспокоит, что мы движемся в неправильную сторону.

В настоящее время в сообществе Николасом предложен временный [регламент жизненного цикла инициатив](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6835/213987) и есть одна [инициатива по расширению онтопика на тему ИБ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6842/213987), которая идёт по этому регламенту.

У меня есть замечания к этому регламенту, которые я считаю существенными и поскольку регламент не является замороженным ответом и в любой момент времени в него могут быть сделаны правки – я буду считать этот регламент временным.

Поскольку я не вижу чёткого механизма внесения правок в регламент и я не собираюсь вносить правки в этот общий ответ без предварительного обсуждения – я хочу в этом топике обсудить некоторые изменения в регламент и, в случае общего консенсуса, что эти правки полезны – попросить управляющего сообществом внести эти изменения в регламент, который ещё раз повторяю должен быть заблокированным.

Часть предложений по регламенту я опубликую отдельным постом, а сейчас хочу предложить более простой механизм регламента на базе т.н. праймериз.

Что в текущем регламенте прописано:

> Крайне хотелось, чтобы каждой инициативе было уделено максимальное
>   внимание со стороны сообщества. Уследить за активным обсуждением сразу
>   нескольких инициатив не всегда возможно. На мой взгляд, следует иметь
>   лишь одну инициативу в стадии активного обсуждения.

и ниже:

> Сроки рассмотрения инициативы
>
> Минимальное время рассмотрения одной инициативы — 4 недели.
>
> **Две недели на обсуждение**. Вопрос–инициатива переходит в стадию рассмотрения сообществом, которая длится две недели с момента
>   получения метки важное.
>
> **Две недели на голосование**. Отсчет начинается либо по прошествии срока рассмотрения, либо с момента публикации последнего ответа.
>   (Таким образом, если на третьей неделе с момента начала обсуждения
>   появляется новый взгляд на проблему в виде ответа, срок работы над
>   инициативой продляется еще на две недели с этого момента.

То есть, каждый месяц управляющий сообществом выбирает из любых тем с меткой  "инициатива" ту, которую он считает наиболее важной. И каждый месяц нас ждёт новая инициатива: первые две недели обсуждаем, вторые две – голосуем.

Я считаю, что можно этот регламент улучшить, но сначала вот какое техническое замечание, которое родилось из наблюдения за текущей инициативой.

Голосование может быть устроено разными способами: авторы, оформляющие вопрос на мете могут просить голосовать кнопками upvote/downvote на самом вопросе, можно на каждом ответе использовать те же кнопки... В принципе, у нас как правило задающие вопрос подбирают подходящие способы в каждом конкретном случае, но часто бывает чехарда, когда голоса дублируются или непонятен механизм.

Так и в этом случае: ответ "за/поддерживаю" (лично я ему поставил downvote), ответ "против" (лично я ему поставил upvote) при этом можно проголосовать upvote за ответ "поддерживаю" и не проголосовать downvote за "против" (я не знаю, какой смысл в этом).

И при этом после этого нужно продублировать свой голос ещё и на самой инициативе (самом вопросе).

Коллеги, вы не находите, что это слишком громоздко?

Я предлагаю простой сценарий:

- кто угодно может разместить сколько угодно инициатив в любой момент времени. Одна инициатива – один топик (один вопрос).
- Голосование по инициативам идёт сколько угодно времени (месяц, два, три), при этом подразумевается, что в этот момент инициатива находится на этапе "праймериз": поощряется голосование за/против на самом вопросе, комментирование вопроса и развёрнутые ответы ([прекрасный образец](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6850/213987)), общественные дискуссии в обсуждениях и чате. Чего быть не должно: никаких ответов "за" и "против" считающихся голосованием за инициативу. Только на самом вопросе.
- Каждый месяц одна из тем по выбору управляющего сообществом объявляется темой месяца и весь месяц идёт голосование по выбранной инициативе. Технически: создаётся новый топик с меткой [важное](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5) в котором даётся ссылка на обсуждение вопроса и фраза "проголосуйте за/против инициативы кнопками слева от вопроса". В конце месяца – history lock на ОБЕ темы и подведение итога по голосованию: создаётся ответе и описывается принятое решение.

Я хочу объяснить, чем эта схема лучше текущей:

- Простой как автомат Калашникова регламент голосования.
- Голосование длится ровно месяц. В условиях когда на мету заходят редко и мало я считаю, что на голосование отводить две недели крайне мало.
- Чёткий и стабильный цикл. Один месяц – одна инициатива голосуется.
- Общественные инициативы могут вызревать и обсуждаться более месяца. В текущей редакции регламента – две недели. Прямо скажу: это очень мало.
- Чёткая и понятная логика выбора инициативы месяца. Мы предполагаем, что управляющий сообществом будет выбирать инициативу, набравшую максимум голосов к моменту начала месяца (выражая этим своё согласие с выбором сообщества), но оставляем за ним вето (инициатива плохо обсуждена – пусть поварится ещё в обсуждениях) и выбор приоритетов на его усмотрение.

Comment: Неоднозначные ощущения по поводу разделения обсуждения и голосования. С одной стороны, я с вами полностью согласен, это было бы крайне логично, да и опыт говорит о том, что голосовать стоит лишь после рассмотрения. Но остается много вопросов о том, как построить итоговую публикацию (например, стоит ли суммировать в одном ответе все предложения, которые как–либо коррелируют между собой), и еще больше вопросов о том, когда можно вопрос переносить из стадии рассмотрения на стадию голосования. Был бы крайне признателен за ваши мысли об этом!

Comment: Отличная инициатива! К сожалению, она не соответствует текущему (как и предлагаемому вами же) регламенту для инициатив. У нас принято обсуждать не больше одной инициативы однременно (Чёткий и стабильный цикл. Один месяц – одна инициатива голосуется.!). Голосование по [текущей обсуждаемой инициативе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6842/) продлится минимум до 7 марта. Пожалуйста, не нарушайте регламент. Вашу инициативу рассмотрим в марте. Если ее выберет на рассмотрение CM. А нет - значит нет.

Comment: @PashaPash Вы путаете обсуждение и голосование по вопросу внесения новых правил. Подразумевается, что в один момент времени лишь одна инициатива, претендующая на внесение в правила сообщества, будет иметь метку важное. Это совершенно не означает, что в это время не может быть других инициатив и обсуждений.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky но это означает, что реальное голосование по этому вот вопросу с изменением регламента будет в марте. А пока все плюсы и минусы на ответах ничего не означают. Мы подождем месяц, повесим на этот вопрос метку. Потом подождем еще две недели, создадим новый вопрос и будем на нем ждать голосов. Причем, (почему-то?) ожидается, что основное обсуждение будет в начале марта, когда метка будет висеть. А по факту - в начале марта будут заплюсованные/заминусованные ответы и полное отсутствие интереса у всех - т.к. за полтора месяца всем станет все равно.

Comment: @edem Я выполнил откат к предыдущей версии вопроса, так как считаю внесённые правки нарушающими исходный замысел. "Ребята давайте без заимстванных слов" должно идти отдельной инициативой, а не без спроса менять существующие посты. Использованное слово было вставлено с определённой лингвистической целью, не надо его менять, если оно вам не нравится.

Comment: @AK вольному воля.

Answer (score 4):

> Этот ответ относится к [устаревшей версии регламента](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/6836/1) и на данный момент неактуален.
>   Прошу обратить внимание на [Альтернативный регламент для инициатив](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6896/178988).

---

## Предлагаемый регламент вообще не нужен.

До этого прекрасно обходились без него и ничего не мешает продолжать так дальше.

### А ещё это регламент уже НЕ РАБОТАЕТ:

- Одновременно обсуждается (причём активно!) 2 инициативы: расширение тематики на социальную инженерию и сам этот регламент. Причём статус обсуждения регламента вообще непонятен.
- Решение блокировать вопросы с обсуждениями проносится вообще мимо меты - обсуждения необходимости блокировки отдельным вопросом не было вообще, вопрос о том, что [нужна другая блокировка, если вообще нужна](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6837/178988) игнорируется, а попытки блокировать старые вопросы [делаются](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/93/revisions).

Получается, этот регламент - просто способ избавиться от неугодных инициатив.

---

**Появился список предполагаемых проблем, которые решает регламент.**
**Отвечаю по ним.**

Сначала кратко:

<kbd>+</kbd> формализация процесса
<kbd>+</kbd> чёткий критерий принятия решения

<kbd>–</kbd> единоличное решения Николаса, что рассматривать как потенциальное правило
      можно просто не допускать неугодные инициативы до стадии голосования
<kbd>–</kbd> направленность на инструменты, а не на людей
<kbd>–</kbd> дублирование и размазывание одного и того же по разным вопросам
<kbd>–</kbd> нет места для экспериментов - принимаемые решения теоретические
<kbd>–</kbd> сложность или невозможность пересмотра решения
<kbd>–</kbd> излишняя сложность - схема голосования непонятна
<kbd>–</kbd> ограниченность числа инициатив, даже если всё уже ясно

По-моему надо:

обсуждать до тех пор, пока есть что сказать
   когда сообщество начнёт следовать результату обсуждения,
      замораживать вопрос и считать правило принятым
   пробовать что-то делать можно сразу, чтобы видеть реакцию сообщества

А теперь подробно:

> (1) формулировка дискуссионных вопросов на Мете зачастую предвзятая и заранее создает ограничения на разнообразие ответов

Это не плохо. Задавая вопрос участник может хотеть подтолкнуть сообщество к какому-то решению. Я не вижу причин считать, что это плохо. Мы не машины, а люди и задавая вопрос мы вкладываем в него какой-то смысл и какую-то предполагаемую цель. Из самого вопроса должно быть понятно, зачем мы его задаём и чего ожидаем получить.

В ответах всегда могут высказаться как согласные, так и несогласные. Плюс, в таком случае ответы будут сосредоточены на цели спрашивающего, а не окажутся подвержены проблеме XY, когда каждый отзывается о предложенном действии, независимо от того принесёт ли оно какую-то пользу и согласуется ли с целями спрашивающего.

А по регламенту у нас получается, что будут создаваться 2 одинаковых вопроса: сначала обсуждаем, потом голосуем. [Как тут.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6769/178988) А потом будет выясняться, что хочется ещё пообсуждать и будут появляться ответы, непонятно как и на что влияющие. Итого, вместо одного нормального вопроса у нас кажа из двух.

Кстати, я, во-первых, так и не понял, как там голосовать, а во-вторых, у меня рука не поднимается поставить плюс намеренному дублю вопроса, хотя я за расширение тематики.

> (2) нет понимания, какие вопросы есть открытая дискуссия, а что есть принятое общественностью правило

Любые вопросы - это открытая дискуссия. С появлением ярко выраженного лидера в обсуждении её следует считать правилом.

Возможно, тут стоит применить блокировку (не буду останавливаться на том, какую именно) и добавить специальную метку, чтобы принятые решения можно было найти.

> (3) непонятно как от одного типа перейти к другому

Обсуждение становится правилом тогда, когда бОльшая часть сообщества уже следует ему на сайте.

Принимать правило чисто теоретически глупо, поскольку никогда нельзя быть уверенным наперёд, как именно всё пойдёт. В какой-то момент надо попробовать и увидеть, что случится. Вот если попробовали, всё классно и сообщество не сопротивляется, обсуждение принимает статус правила.

> (4) за счет отсутствия четких правил мы можем «по-быстрому» провести одно правило за день 5ю участниками, а другое обсуждаем по несколько месяцев и имеем по 50–60 голосов (очевидно, что во втором случае правило действительно принимает сообщество, первое — нет)

Ну не обсуждать же каждую мелочь по месяцу? Например, синоним метки [при +6/-2](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6196/178988) вполне можно принять за день, а ту же [Социальную инженерию](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6769/178988) можно обсуждать долго.

Comment: (вздыхая) Ну плюс-то я поставлю, потому что солидарен, но вообще-то вы могли и сами подобную тему поднять отдельно, глядишь бы и удалось откатить регламент. Пока что вы даже не подняли вопрос "какую проблему мы решаем этим регламентом", ограничиваясь [отдельными фразами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6835/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%83#comment27100_6836).

Comment: А мне нравятся ответы Qwertiy, часто в ответах всё разжёвввается и раскладывается до мельчайших деталей, и это конечно бывает что действительно надо. Но ответы Qwertiy активизируют мышление в человеке, мне приходится самому думать а не получать готовую кашу в рот. Написано ясно и сразу по сути. Можно и 10 страниц написать, но ясно не станет, а можно сказать одну две фразы и сразу всё станет ясно.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин к сожалению, люди из одной-двух фраз могут понять "сразу всё", но совершенно не то, что действительно важно. Голоса у таких ответов могут отразить мнение сообщества, но никак не повлияют на "информированность" этого мнения.

Comment: @D-side я думаю многое зависит от желания понять и прислушаться, даже если изначально не согласен. Так как некоторые думают что всегда сами правы и знают всё лучше всех.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин ответ не даёт никаких новых причин прислушаться или усомниться в своей правоте. Это примерно как в споре ответить фразой "я не согласен". Описывает ситуацию, но никак на неё не влияет, это не двигает спор к "истине" (которая якобы рождается в споре).

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин (на удалённый комментарий) Кому не даёт "никаких новых причин"? Никому из тех, кого он должен склонить к смене точки зрения.

Comment: Я для себя не вижу смысла спорить или склонять кого-то к смене точки зрения, собственная точка зрения это ответственность самого человека. Лично мне данный ответ помог задуматься, и активизировать мой личный творческий процесс мышления на интересную мне тему в результате чего я написал свой ответ. Если для кого-то такого нет, то такого нет, это не хорошо не плохо, это данность.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не могли бы вы подробно раскрыть вашу мысль? Почему не нужен? Что станет хуже, если мы формально опишем процессы? На данный момент ваше утверждение – это [доказательство авторитетом](https://cs8.pikabu.ru/post_img/2017/05/28/10/1495988212153376627.jpg). На мой взгляд, подобный способ обоснования правильности выбора правил не подходит для нашего сообщества.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, обоснование твоё любимое: "нет проблемы, значит и решать её не нужно". Я не вижу, чтобы с инициативами была какая-то массовая проблема.

Comment: @Qwertiy Проблемы следующие: (1) формулировка дискуссионных вопросов на Мете зачастую предвзятая и заранее создает ограничения на разнообразие ответов; (2) нет понимания, какие вопросы есть открытая дискуссия, а что есть принятое общественностью правило; (3) непонятно как от одного типа перейти к другому; (4) за счет отсутствия четких правил мы можем «по-быстрому» провести одно правило за день 5ю участниками, а другое обсуждаем по несколько месяцев и имеем по 50–60 голосов (очевидно, что во втором случае правило действительно принимает сообщество, первое — нет).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ок, вот созданный вами вопрос-инициатива: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6842/. **Ни одна из проблем, кроме (4) в нем не решена**.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, ответ дополнен

Comment: До дополнения ответа на нём было было +8 -5.

Comment: А я вот поддерживаю регламент во всём (даже в принципе «не более одной инициативы одновременно», чтобы была возможность вести перепалку, возобновляемую после очередной поправки в инициативу, а не распыляться на три-четыре потока), кроме сроков проведения. Здесь я разделяю мнение @AK (особенно понравилась идея пробных вопросов по теме ([п. 2 ответа по ссылке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6882/208074))).

Comment: @Arhad, одна инициатива за раз - в принципе как раз правильно. Но я бы уточнил до "одна крупная инициатива за раз". Всякую мелочёвку можно обсуждать одновременно, потому что то, что мы можем что-то полгода мусолить и это не должно вставать блокером для всего остального.

Comment: @Qwertiy, думаю, что мелочёвка не входит в понятие «[инициатива, которая улучшит сообщество](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6835/208074)». Как я понял, предложение Николаса больше про глобальные вещи (уровня введения новых правил или создания прецедентов). То есть голосование по, например, слиянию/разделению меток можно проводить как раньше.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, правильно ли я понял посыл вашего предложения по инициативам? ^^^

Comment: @Arhad, теоретическое обсуждение инициатив бесполезно. Нужно хоть что-то попробовать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, поэтому я и поддерживаю идею AK по демонстрационным вопросам. К примеру, хотите видеть социальную инженерию не сайте (инициатива уже висит) — опубликуйте хотя бы пару-тройку вопросов по соц. инженерии. При текущем регламенте больше всё равно не успеть, но по крайней мере станет понятно, как проходит реальное обсуждение со знанием дела и насколько оно укладывается в предлагаемый регламент. И по окончании можно будет внести в этот регламент изменения на основе реальных наблюдений.

Comment: @Qwertiy, к слову. спорную инициативу по домашним заданиям также можно будет пересмотреть, основываясь на качественных примерах вопросов.

Comment: @Arhad это при условии, что CM вообще решит выбрать инициативу по домашкам на рассмотрение. может и не выбрать. и в следующий раз не выбрать, и еще раз не выбрать. странно, что никто не замечает - но в такой схеме не сообщество решает, что оно хочет поменять в правилах, а ровно один человек-фильтр.

Comment: @PashaPash, можно написать Николасу в чате и рассказать, почему домашним заданиям вновь необходимо уделить внимание, и чем принятое решение спорно в свете качества уже имеющихся вопросов по домашним заданиям. Но тут уже надо проводить исследование доли закрытых/удалённых вопросов и причин закрытия (чтобы подкрепить свою позицию цифрами, а не голыми эмоциями и личными впечатлениями). И ещё надо суметь доказать, что плохи не некоторые (ленивые) вопрошающие, а именно сама инициатива. То есть дело не в CM — не инициатору пересмотра, так управляющему придётся проделывать эту колоссальную работу.

Comment: @Arhad и тут управляющий говорит - я не считаю это проблемой, все нормально, никаких проблем с "домашкой", или "закрытием как опросник" я не вижу. приходите через месяц.

Comment: @PashaPash Поэтому я и указал на необходимость поиска обоснования. Понятное дело, что управляющий никогда с бухты барахты не будет пускать на пересмотр инициативу, принятое решение по которой имеет отрыв по голосам. Да и можно припомнить причину закрытия «работа за автора», которую как ввели, так и убрали из-за злоупотреблений при её использовании. Это ещё один минус против выпуска инициативы на пересмотр (существующее решение самое безопасное по отношению к базе вопросов).

Comment: @Arhad ок, давайте я покажу вам ситуацию с другой стороны. это вопрос по смене регламента - инициатива? но ведь у нас уже есть один вопрос-инициатива в обсуждении! (https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6842/). так что давайте перестанем обсуждать регламент, и сфокусируемся на расширении онтопика в сторону инженерии. а регламент приходите обсуждать 3-го марта!

Comment: @PashaPash Самое главное в инициативах — не навредить. Получив метку важное, получив сроки и какие–то более или менее понятные правила игры, началось обсуждение. Заметьте, исходный вопрос провисел почти две недели без каких–либо ответов вообще, и вроде бы, как говорится в этом ответе, за большинство голосов его бы можно было бы и принять! Но это не так, многие против.

Comment: @Qwertiy `Это не плохо.` — На мой взгляд, это _очень_ плохо. Да, мы люди, у каждого есть своя позиция, согласен, но мы не должны жертвовать свободами всего сообщества в угоду единиц. От постановки вопрос зависит многое. И если постановка вопроса такая, что сразу видно лишь одно лучшее решение, то это уже замануха какая–то. Вопрос в том, хотим ли мы рабочие рациональные простые правила или те, которые были продавлены обманным путем?

Comment: @Qwertiy `синоним метки при +6/-2 вполне можно принять за день` — правила созданы только для _вопросов–инициатив_, которые претендуют стать общественным правилом, то есть, можно сказать, новым разделом справочного центра, а не для всех вопросов на Мете. Синонимы меток к списку вопросов–инициатив относить не стоит.

Comment: @Qwertiy `Обсуждение становится правилом тогда, когда бОльшая часть сообщества` — вопрос что такое «_когда_» и «_бОльшая часть_». К примеру, для одного участника может быть очевидно что время уже настало при +3/-2, а кто–то будет уверен, что +55/-45 — не есть выбор бОльшинства, а лишь половины. Пожалуйста, давайте будем конкретней. Подскажите, как вы определите «большинство» и «время, когда обсуждение завершилось»? Без этих понятий, мы не можем принять ни одно правило, так как без общих правил это будет лишь субъективная позиция принимающего и все обсуждения теряют любой смысл.

Comment: @Arhad Да, вы совершенно верно поняли! Вопрос–инициатива — это вопрос, который нацелен на создание или изменения правила, которе может претендовать быть в справочном центре.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, метки - это, конечно же, крайность. Я про то, что инициативы бывают разные - с какими-то всё ясно, а с другими надо разбираться долго. И не надо их все под одну гребёнку. Метки - это лишь утрированный пример голосования, которое нет смысла долго держать.

Comment: @Qwertiy Отлично! Ведь никто и не предлагал использовать какие–либо процессы в отношении каких–либо вопросов, которые не затрагивают правила сообщества. Это добавили вы в ваш ответ. На основе этого допущения «о голосовании за метки» вы пытаетесь убедить сообщество в отсутствии необходимости процессов для введения новых правил. Думаю, если мы смотрим на ситуацию одинаково, стоит этот пункт убрать из ответа, так как сейчас ваш комментарий противоречит ответу.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, не противоречит. Суть в том, что есть крайности.

Comment: @Qwertiy Вы в ответе убеждаете людей, что инициатива не нужна, так как не верно применять процессы к синонимам меток. Но этого никто нигде не предлагал! Пожалуйста, давайте рационально подходить к дискуссии без ввода в заблуждение. Если этого нет в предложении, не стоит этим и аргументировать против. Инициатива по умолчанию создана для вопросов, которые не являются «мелочью» и затрагивают большенство участников сообщества. Время ожидания необходимо, чтобы дать возможность принять участие в голосовании тем, кто за ходит на сайт чуть реже, чем наиболее активные участники.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ну ок, вы показали, что метка важное привлекает внимание к вопросу. как из этого следует, что реальное голосование по вот этому вот вопросу стоит отложить на вторую половину марта?

Comment: @Qwertiy Пожалуйста, не путайте голосование (вопрос изменения тематики) и обсуждение (отзыв о регламенте). Регламент был создан исключительно для вопросов, которые подразумевают голосование и единое решение, на основе которого будет создано правило. Результатом данного обсуждения будет улучшение инициативы в каком–либо виде. Здесь важны все ответы и комментарии.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, их нужно путать. Потому что это одно и то же.

Comment: @Qwertiy Пожалуйста, поясните, почему? (П.С. Я не могу забраться к вам в голову и понять, что вы имеете в виду. Сейчас все обсуждение с вами строится по доказательству авторитетом.)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, потому что рассмотрение критериев и принятие решение делается в процессе обсуждения, а не "я проспал всё обсуждение, сейчас я за месяц всё прочитаю, подумаю и галочку поставлю, причём неважно, что высказаться при этом я уже не могу".

Answer (score 4):

Ответ ниже является рудиментом. Текущее положение дел описано в ответе к вопросу «[Альтернативный регламент для инициатив](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6899/6)»

---

На мой взгляд, любую проблему лучше понять на конкретном примере. Некоторое время назад в нашем сообществе был [вопрос о сборе приветствий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6666/6), которые мы хотим автоматически удалять. Данный вопрос создан лишь с одной целью — постараться охватить все многообразие примеров приветствий. Качественно сделать это можно лишь вместе, когда каждый заинтересованный расскажет то, что знает. Заметим, что [вопрос о необходимости удаления приветствий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/93/6) как таковой обсуждался несколькими годами ранее и получил однозначную поддержку сообщества. Был и [вопрос про автоматическое удаление приветствий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/465). Но! Вместо улучшающей правки общего ответа, с вариантом приветствий, был опубликован ответ, цитирую полность:

> А я по-прежнему против. Приветствия не мешают.

Возникает вопрос: что теперь делать? То есть в сообществе есть участники, не согласные с вырезанием приветствий. Игнорировать мнения участников, конечно же не стоит. Чтобы сообщество развивалось, нам крайне важно подходить к вопросу выбора правил рационально, и если у кого–то есть серьезные основания полагать, что мы допускаем ошибку, необходимо эти обоснования выслушать и рассмотреть. Но публикуя подобные ответы участники, по сути, нарушают логическую целостность вопроса по сбору примеров приветствий. Правильное действие в данном случае, на мой взгляд, вынести вопрос на рассмотрение *отдельной публикацией*, что я и предложил сделать, в [комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6666/#comment-26058) к процитированного выше ответу.

Проблема в том, что в результате появился, на мой взгляд, не вопрос–инициатива, а [вопрос–утверждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6671/), никак не подкрепленный обоснованиями или доводами, не рассматривающий суть исходной проблемы, не раскрывающий суть настоящей (почему мы вообще должны отказаться от предыдущего *принятого* сообществом решения?) Вопрос не призывает рационально и детальном рассмотреть проблему и способы ее решения, а просто содержит утверждение.

Опять возникает тот же самый вопрос: что теперь делать? Участник скажет, что вот, сообщество его единогласно поддержало! И добавляя в настройки сайта регулярное выражение по автоматическому удалению мы идем в разрез с мнением сообщества. Но на самом деле это же не так! Рассмотрения никакого не было! Было высказано *мнение в одно предложение* и кто–то проголосовал «за», то ли поддерживая активность самого автора, то ли разделяя это мнение, то ли по каким–либо другим личным мотивам. И никто не знает ответ почему и за что люди голосуют в этом вопросе. (Как минимум, я не знаю, что от меня, как участника, ожидается в этом вопросе.) И вообще, что следует сейчас делать? Отменить инициативу полность? Не ясно и когда считать, что вопрос получил достаточно внимания сообщества? Как численно понять, что мы принимаем решение от мнения большинства активных участников? Более того, крайне неочевидно, что есть мнение большинства и как его посчитать? Голоса в вопросе, в сумме разделяющих позицию ответов или в каком–то одном ответе? Понятно лишь одно – вопрос не может служить побуждением к принятию решения. Сам вопрос выражает позицию участника без описания какой–либо проблемы и того, за что и как должны и голосуют участники в данной ситуации. Подчеркну, вопрос должен отражать проблему, а все мысли о решении проблемы, в том числе автора вопроса, следует размещать в ответах. В обратном случае, мы рискуем создать прецедент, когда ответами будут лишь противопоставления вопросу, а все аналогичные мысли публиковаться не будут, хотя они могли бы заметно улучшить предлагаемое решение. Если мы хотим иметь лучшие процессы на основе коллективного опыта, подобного допускать ни в коем случае нельзя.

Подчеркну, это не первый случай, подобных примеров в истории сообщества их было несколько. Например, можно посмотреть историю вопросов рассмотрения формулировок причин закрытия (к слову, процесс отчасти взят как опыт рассмотрения именно причин закрытия вопросов).

Были и другие примеры, на мой взгляд, крайне неоднозначных принятий решений на основе голосования сообщества. Например, [голосование за модераторов общего чата](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5496/). Казалось бы, к вопросу выборов мы подошли внимательно, формально описав требования и к откликам кандидатов, и к процессу голосования. Но, пожалуйста, обратите внимание на распределение голосов и за кандидатов: +24/-14; +6/-3; +16/-22, то есть за кого–то проголосовало 38 человек, а за кого–то — 9. Так быть не должно. На мой взгляд, это подтверждение факта, что если правила не совершенны, то этим обязательно кто–то воспользуется.

**Отсутствие понятных процессов порождает «нестандартные обходы правил», которые приводят к нерациональным решениям и последующую за этим анархию.**

На мой взгляд, невозможно сесть и придумать оптимальные процессы, но начать определенно стоит, если мы хотим принимать решения, которые на самом деле отражают позицию большинства.

Пожалуйста, оставляйте ваши отзывы о существующих процессах, создавайте новые вопросы–обсуждения! Совершенно точно, мы будем непрерывно улучшать правила и процессы что–то добавляя, что–то удаляя. Наша задача — создать минимально возможные, простые, понятные всем и *рациональные* правила, основанные на дискуссии участников с внимательным рассмотрением проблем

Comment: 0. При возникновении сложностей с конкретными вопросами, надо их решать с этими конкретными вопросами, а не со всем подряд. 1. _"А я по-прежнему против. Приветствия не мешают."_ - в контексте того вопроса это было высказывание против автоматического вырезания. Пересмотреть полностью политику относительно приветствий я не предлагал.

Comment: 2. Голосование по кандидатам: +1 - я хочу чтобы этот кандидат стал владельцем чата, -1 - я хочу чтобы этот кандидат НЕ стал владельцем чата, 0 - у меня нет причин хотеть видеть его владельцем чата, но и ничего против него я не имею. То, что за одного из них всего 9 голосов означает нейтральное отношение к кандидату большинства участников. Это нормально и не содержит никакой проблемы.

Comment: @Qwertiy (2) Я вижу это иначе: отклик с наименьшим количеством голосов был опубликован за несколько часов до завершения голосования. Остается только гадать, как распределились бы голоса, если бы мы подождали две недели. (1) Как я писал, это не первый прецедент. Видно, что есть как минимум непонимание, каким образом задать вопрос так, чтобы сообщество дало максимально хороший отклик (максимум совершенно разных развернуты ответов). Также, например, у меня, есть непонимание, что считать правилом, подлежащим исполнению, а что открытой дискуссией. На эти вопросы отвечает предлагаемый процесс.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky по моему мнению нету необходимости делать излишнюю демократию, вы лично можете координировать различные процессы, без какого либо объяснения правилами. Если эти решения будут разумны, и сделаны с Любовью к сайту то это будет только на благо.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky мне кажется что суть не в том что бы всё делать на основе равноправного голосования и формального соблюдения правил, а в том что бы сайт развивался на благо создателям, пользователям и гостям.

Answer (score 3):

У каждого человека есть ум, разум, логика, голова, мышление... Это универсальные механизмы позволяющие решить любые ситуации.

Вводя кучу правил, а правило часто это жёстко зафиксированный стереотип поведения, мы мешаем логике, голове, уму, разуму, мышлению нормально работать. Есть ситуации где лучше и логичнее поступить так так-то и так-то, и это может быть вообще не по правилам, а если мы поступим по правилам то это будет просто глупо и неправильно. В результате получается что у правил есть исключения и для их покрытия создаются новые правила. Таким образом вместо того что бы просто адекватно мыслить мы имеем свод, талмуд правил, которые всё-равно мало кто или даже никто не будет читать.

Создавая кучу лишних правил мы мешаем функционированию естественных процессов и механизмов как в самом сообществе так и в каждом человеке кто их использует.

Кроме того в интернете и вообще в мире есть очень много сообществ, форумов, групп, сайтов. Везде могут быть свои правила и порядки. Разве разумно на каждом таком сайте читать десятки страниц правил этого сайта, запоминать всё это и следовать этому, если можно просто быть адекватным, разумным, уважать других итп, это личная работа и ответственность каждого.

Я не говорю что правила вообще не нужны, но их объём и содержание должны быть разумным и адекватным, и правила должны вносить ясность а не запутывать суть и мешать естественному мышлению делать свою работу.

Если более конкретно по поводу именно этих правил что в вопросе. Например вопрос который реально решить за 2 недели, теперь должен ждать 1 месяца для решения, может ситуация и редкая но вполне возможная. Или вопрос который можно и за год не решить опять же будет решаться за один месяц. В чём смысл в этих ограничениях? Просто мозг и ум отключаются от работы и должны теперь следовать правилам. Кроме того то что на повестке должна быть только одна инициатива. В чём смысл? Я например могу решать одновременно несколько вопросов (зависит от самих вопросов) если вопросы простые то их можно решить и быстро и параллельно...

Как это может быть (впрочем как это и было):

- Каждый вопрос решать столько времени сколько он требует для решения. И для этого не нужно создавать правило, это и так очевидно и естественно.
- Одновременно можно решать столько вопросов сколько можно, адекватно и удобно в каждой конкретной ситуации.

PS: Ситуация может измениться, и тогда старые правила устаревают, приходится переписывать новые, или действовать уже неадекватно времени и ситуации. То есть на поддержание свода правил уходит много времени и энергий.

Ум, разум, логика итп они универсальны, и действуют в зависимости от ситуации, в моменте Сейчас. Ситуация изменилась - решение будет уже другое.

PS2: Может быть я чересчур резко выразился. Конечно есть много ситуаций где правила нужны, но думаю главное что бы они не конфликтовали с умом, логикой итп, гармонично дополняли друг друга.

Comment: Я бы хотел, чтобы вопросы по расширению онтопика решались даже больше, чем за месяц и тем более две недели. И без этого постоянная чехарда в правилах, большинство за метой даже не пытаются следить. И вашему ответу, и ответу Квертия и моему вопросу не хватает пояснений Николаса (начать нужно именно с пояснений "какую проблему хотели решить" и "все ли инициативы требуют такого пристального внимания всего сообщества"), а он пока ни здесь не ответил, ни в чате не вышел на связь.

Comment: @AK я писал не только по именно этому вопросу, а более общее. Хочется расшевелить людей. Кроме того то что я написал важно мне самому для понимания правил и процессов которые стоят за этим.

Comment: Хороший ответ. А еще надо держать в голове, что для многих основным является (обычно оно даже явно не формулируется) такое правило -- *если нельзя, но очень хочется, то все равно можно*