# Как правильно оформить вопрос про рефакторинг кода?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

У меня есть небольшая задача. Смысл её в том, что бы сдать. Есть код, мною скопированный и дорабатываемый. Нужно довести код до ума, но за что я не берусь, это не к чему не приводит.

Выхода вижу 2:

1. Начать писать код с полного нуля, разбираясь в его деталях;
2. Оформить его ru.stackoverflow.com с просьбой поддержки, оставив тем самым его в истории глобального интернета.

Могу ли я написать его с просьбой:

1. Провести рефакторинг;
2. Дополнить его и довести его до требуемого результата.

Как лучше оформить?

Comment: Нужен ли ваш код для "истории глобального интернета" - вопрос неоднозначный. Да и для серьезных вопросов по code review есть специальный сайт на stackexchange - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Вы про [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/920259/С-Как-запустить-программу) вопрос? Я же привёл ссылку на оформление минимального самодостаточного вопроса. 1) Разбейте вашу задачу на подзадачи. 2) Некоторые подзадачи вы наверняка сможете написать сами. 3) Для всех подзадач, которые вы ПОПЫТАЛИСЬ решить сами, но возникла ошибка, задайте соответствующий вопрос. Уверен, что таким образом, вы и будущие читатели получат максимальную пользу

Comment: @cppquestions т.е. несколько вопросов из одной программы, решающие одну задачу - это нормально?

Comment: @Kyper зависит от поставки задачи. Можно поставить задачу так: "мне задали X, сделайте X". А можно n задач: 1) `int void main();` выдаёт ошибку  Y, в чём проблема? 2) `int main(int argc, char** argv[])` выдаёт предупреждение для 2 параметра, почему? И так далее

Comment: @cppquestions, кажется раньше я так пробовал. Значит буду анализировать и стараться решать по другому. Вопрос тот, разбираю этот код с вопроса

Answer (score 7):

Давайте называть вещи своими именами: если у вас есть чужой код и вы хотите, чтобы вам его кто-то переписал — это не "рефакторинг", это "техническое задание" ака "напишите всё за меня". Такие вопросы могут набрать очень много минусов от постоянных посетителей и быть закрытыми.

Рефакторингом у нас и на [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) называется "мы вам расскажем, чем ваш код плох — но переписывать вам придётся самому". Мы не злыдни и может быть даже какие-то фрагменты кода покажем, как лучше — но не обязаны приводить полностью код.

Кроме того, если код не работает — на рефакторинг он не принимается.

Подробнее можно почитать по ссылкам:

- [Политика относительно вопросов с инспекцией кода (code review)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1761/213987)
- [Описание метки инспекция-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0/info)

Ну и просто полистайте [вопросы по этой метке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0), чтобы посмотреть [хорошие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0?sort=votes&pageSize=50) и [цитируемые](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) образцы.

А вот начать разбираться — это похвальный вариант. Будут конкретные вопросы — приходите, задавайте вопросы, поможем.

Обычно у нас принято писать отдельные вопросы в отдельных темах, поэтому если у вас разнородные примеры — дайте их отдельно, возможно указав исходный вопрос, где есть полный пример кода. Если вы видите, что у вас при написании *МИНИМАЛЬНОГО* [примера кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) получилось два разных куска кода — это однозначно РАЗНЫЕ вопросы.

Вопросы вида два-в-одном легко могут быть закрыты как слишком общие, чтобы  вы не раздумывали куда поставить галку — тому кто ответил на первый подвопрос, на второй или третий. Ну и отвечать в такие вопросы неполностью меньше желающих.