# Закрыли вопрос и не дали ответа =(

Tags: обсуждение, модерация

Впервые пришел на этот форум, а тут взяли и просто так закрыли мой вопрос. Хотел узнать про правильную последовательность подключения файлов в head, ну и про правильное расположение viewpoert, utf-8. Я не понимаю, почему данный вопрос не по теме?
[Правильная последовательность подключения файлов в head](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1375960/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-head)

UPD: Вот, прикола ради закрыли еще один вопрос.
[Удаление последнего символа в Html разметке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1376589/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-html-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5)

**Ну и как тут задавать вопросы, если их сразу же закрывают.**

Comment: вот кстати только что заметил, что изначальный код ты удалил со второго вопроса, где показывал как решал регуляркой....полагаю на это ориентировался Grundy - что "нет своей попытки". Некоторые на это обращают внимание...бывает. В целом, если что-то пробовал, но не получалось - лучше всегда оставлять в вопросе, потому что это может помочь отвечающему подкорректировать его и всё. А может и нет. Плюс не будут триггериться закрывающие))

Answer (score 10):

Вы должны понять, что данный ресурс существует продолжительное количество времени. И сущствуют правила поведения, хорошего тона и уважения к задающим вопросы и отвечающим.

Первое с чего надо начать, так это с изучения [Справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help). Большинство ситуаций там и описано.

Например, [Как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), а так же [Что означает статус вопроса «закрыт» или «требует правки»? Почему некоторые вопросы «требуют правки»?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

Конкретнее, первый вопрос закрыт под данной причине:

> не по теме — **каждое сообщество само решает**, какие вопросы допустимы, а какие — нет.

> Скорее всего, данный вопрос не соответствует тематике сайта.

> Воспользуйтесь правкой, если вы можете переписать вопрос так, чтобы он соответствовал тематике сайта.

Закрыть вопрос или нет решает не один злой человек, это объективное решение активных членов сообщества.

**UPD START**

Для тех, кто не любит разбираться и считает, что вопрос закрыт единолично @Grundy.

Из очереди проверок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И далее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И только после этого вопрос переоткрыл @Qwertiy

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD END**

И последнее прочтите [Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Уверен, что вы поймете, почему был закрыт данный вопрос.

Мой личный взгляд на ваш вопрос. Вы пишете:"Я не уверен в правильности...". Это хорошо сомневаться в том или ином, но сомнения можно обосновать субъективно (я так чувствую, но не знаю почему), либо объективно. Например, вы прикладываете ссылку на документацию или выдержку из нее, где рассматривается данный вопрос. И у вас сомнения, что вы правильно обосновали/применили описанное. Либо, встречаются исключительные варианты и написанная программа ведет себя неожиданно. Вам помогут, более чем уверен.

Как красная тряпка на быка действуют вопросы "решите, проверьте" без мыслей и попыток решения автора. Встречаются отдельные индивиды, которые считают, что здесь им должны решить, вплоть до того, что начинают писать: "разберись в моем вопросе" и проч.

Ответьте сами себе на вопросы: "Почему члены *ruSO* должны проверять ваш код на правильность?", "Почему вы считаете, что ваш код/последоватьность подключения *не правильные*"

И более, в комментариях к вопросу вам дали ответ, в том формате в котором задан сам вопрос.

Comment: "Решите, проверьте" без мыслей и попыток решения автора". Там есть моя мысль и моё решение, я лишь просил мнение более грамотных людей. "Что здесь им должны решить, вплоть до того, что начинают писать" Ну если посудить логически, то здесь во всех вопросах люди просят разобраться и проч. Тогда смысл задавать вопрос, если в нём не хотят разбираться и просто посылают куда подальше. Во втором вопросе, я все указал по теме, удаления последнего символа при помощи JS. Человек дал мне ответ в комментах, я все понял, но кто-то все равно закрыл тему.

Comment: Обратите внимание, на ссылки, которые я вам оставил. Обратите внимание, сколько вопросов отвечено и сколько не закрыто. Подумайте, что не так. "Кто-то все равно закрыл тему" - это не один человек, это несколько совершенно разных не связанных между собой людей. Все, что вы пишете ваше субъективное мнение, как и мое, которое я оставил на в конце ответа.

Comment: Закрыл две темы один и тот же человек, да и еще повторно закрывал один и тот же вопрос.  Куда можно скинуть скриншот в качестве док-во?

Comment: Не надо доказательств, ваш вопрос не закрыт. Прошу вас принять правила сообщества и почитать информацию по ссылкам

Comment: Так его открыли после публикации этого сообщения на мете. Один и тот же человек закрывал первый вопрос 2-3 раза подряд. Потом этот же человек решил закрыть мой второй вопрос по приколу и ему это удалось.

Comment: Закроем эту бессмысленную полемику. Мое личное мнение, что ваш вопрос не несет пользы сообществу и базе знаний на русском языке (нет документации, нет основания для сомнений). Еще раз, когда у вас будет больше репутации, вы сами сможете оставлять тревоги, голосовать за закрытие/переоткрытие вопросов, вносить правки и всячески администравно активничать. Я надеюсь, что вы понимаете, что я вам пытаюсь донести. Это мое мнение. А овтечать за действия и мнения других я не намерен. Точка

Comment: @Зеленыйчел Здесь добавлю ссылку [Как создать вопрос на инспекцию кода, чтобы не закрыли](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1761/209304). Надеюсь, это вам поможет в дальнейшем

Comment: Благодарю за ваше мнение =)

Comment: "Закрыть вопрос или нет решает не один злой человек, это объективное решение активных членов сообщества." - это немного не соответствует реальному положению дел. Закрыть и открыть вопрос одним голосом может модератор, что и произошло в данном случае. Вопросы вполне нормальные при этом.

Comment: @insolor на гранди уже не раз жаловались) странно что он ещё модератор)  (как и Qwertiy если честно :)))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Qwertiy откатил решение 4-х участников, включая другого модератора, а виноват все равно Гранди. %)

Comment: @PashaPash они оба беспредельщики.

Comment: PashaPash, ну а что делать? Qwertiy как поборник справедливости и дебютантов ринулся в неравную схватку с древним злом и вышел победителем. Оно и неудивительно, ведь добро побеждает зло.

Comment: @insolor добавил update в вопрос, а то тут недопонимание какое-то. Закрыть вопрос - не единоличное решение Grundy

Comment: @Dmitry, по первому вопросу - допустим, закрыто 4 голосами, Qwertiy переоткрыл, Grundy закрыл. По второму вопросу: закрыто единолично Grundy ("вызвано опечаткой или другой проблемой" - какой блин опечаткой?), переоткрыто 5 голосами, перезакрыто Grundy единолично, переоткрыто 3 голосами, в том числе Qwertiy.

Comment: Со стороны выглядит так, что Grundy просто закрывает вопросы, которые ему лично не нравятся. Это уже скорее вахтерство, а не модерирование.

Comment: @insolor я по первому вопросу отвечал. Я не пытаюсь обелить или очернить кого-то. Мое мнение так и осталось тем, что вопрос может быть закрытым без потерь. Единственное позитивное в том, что вопрос переоткрыли, так это поддержать ТС, который не так давно зарегестрировался (сарказм, естественно).

Comment: Забанить обоих! :)

Comment: вот это был бы холивар, если бы модераторы друг друга банили =)

Comment: "Мое мнение так и осталось тем, что вопрос может быть закрытым без потерь." - это ваше мнение, мое мнение - совершенно противоположное (оба вопроса вполне нормальные даже в исходной формулировке). В целом, у кого-то из участников всегда будет тенденция оставлять вопросы открытыми, у кого-то - зачистить все некачественные вопросы (привет, andreymal). Чтобы был какой-то консенсус, и нужно голосование. Тут консенсус нарушен из-за вмешательства модераторов.

Comment: @insolor абсолютно, это мое и даже субъективное мнение. Я борюсь с желанием оставлять тревоги и голосовать за закрытие с каждым сообщением, которое мне не нравится. Некоторым достаточно написать комментарий и они исправляют вопрос/ответ. А некоторым не достаточно и 3х лет, чтобы понять как это функционирует. По началу я тоже агрился на всякую "надуманную несправделивость". А сейчас, ну ок, заминусили, закрыли.

Comment: Грюнди не хочет отдавать власть Алексею Шиманскому. Грюнди хочет узурпировать власть и передать её по наследству.

Comment: @Хлебушек у Алексея Шиманского есть более интересные и реальные дела, чем жить на данном ресурсе и следить за всеми))

Comment: А как отвечать в комментах, в ответ другому человеку как делаете вы.

Comment: Всю власть  Алексею Шиманскому и Qwertiy!

Comment: @Dmitry а второй вопрос был закрыт единолично Грюнди.

Answer (score 8):

Выскажу своё мнение, конкретно насчёт вопроса [Правильная последовательность подключения файлов в head](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1375960/).

### Насчёт вопроса

Суть вопроса и заголовка различаются. В заголовке вы спрашиваете *о подключение сторонних файлов к странице*, а в теле вопроса ещё и о мета-тегах. Но опустим этот момент.

Основная проблема всё же в том, что об этом написано 100500 статей, а так же об этом говорится в момент изучения HTML (допустим [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/The_head_metadata_in_HTML)).

### Насчёт действия модератора

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В целом такое может коснуться многих.. Но считаю это не правильным.
Основная причина закрытия - `Не подходит для этого сайта`, но как раз таки подходит, т.к. на данном сайте есть теги [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) и [инспекция-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0).

То что данных меток не было изначально - не совсем проблема, т.к. автор может о них не знать, да и у более активных участников есть возможность редактировать метки, почему они не были добавлены изначально - другой вопрос.

### В заключение

**Автору** вопроса предлагаю правильно формулировать свои вопросы, не только, чтобы вопрос не был закрыт, но и правильная формулировка даёт больше шансов на решение (порой даже без публикации вопроса на SO).
Ну и изначально поискать решение самостоятельно, т.к. SO по сути база знаний и большая часть ответов уже находится на сайте, и задавать вопрос не обязательно.

Не собираюсь указывать **модератору**, но поведение **Grundy** считаю не допустимым.
Опять же отталкиваясь от того, что от данного модератора нет никаких сообщений в данном вопросе, только закрытие, по сути без пояснений.
Возможно связанно с плохим настроением ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

**ИМХО**.

Comment: Согласен, что модератор мог быть чуть терпимее, но он не был и этого его право. Вопрос широкий и ответ данный на него это подтверждает. У меня нет оснований для сомнений в квалификации отвечающего, но прочитав его всплывают такие оговорки как "традиционно..., рекомендации..." и прочее, широко. Спасибо, @Qwertiy♦ за то, что ответил, но я надеюсь, что в дальнейшем ТС будет детальнее подходить к своим вопросам.

Comment: Привет Денис. Абсолютно согласен с таким ответом, как с языка сняли. Что касается настроения, то подобные выпады в зависимости от настроения на сайте неуместны. Свой характер, принципы и прочие личные амбиции нужно учиться придерживать. ...а тут что-то часто бывает плохое настроение у данного персонажа

Comment: @Dmitry по поводу недопустимого поведения. Вопрос был закрыт 4-мя участниками через очередь проверок, а модератор Qwertiy проигнорировал решение остальных участников и просто переоткрыл вопрос. да еще и устроил войну закрытия с другим модератором. Вот такое точно недопустимо.

Comment: @PashaPash все интереснее и интереснее. В своём ответе я указывал, что это решение не одного человека, но большинство увидело верхушку

Comment: @PashaPash, вопросу было место быть на сайте, его закрыли из-за того, что лень стало редактировать. А всего-то нужно было добавить метку [tag:инспекция-кода]